# force_ssl causes never-ending redirects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ssl

Rails 3.1.3

With force_ssl in place I get this redirect over and over and it never ends. I am going to the https url so I'm not sure why else it would complain. Ideas?

```
Started GET "/app/admin/calendar" for 69.64.227.254 at 2012-02-13 19:52:44 +0000
  Processing by Admin::CalendarsController#show as HTML
  User Load (1.0ms) SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 21 ORDER BY lower(first) ASC LIMIT 1
  Account Load (0.6ms) SELECT "accounts".* FROM "accounts" WHERE "accounts"."id" = 23 AND (accounts.deleted_at IS NULL) LIMIT 1
Redirected to https://www.mydomain.net/app/admin/calendar
Completed 301 Moved Permanently in 4ms
```

Comment: What's the web server you're using to run the app?

Comment: Please post your nginx configuration.

Comment: Thanks guys, I seem to have it working now by doing all the work in nginx and removing force_ssl from rails.

Answer (score 7):

Answered here: [Why am I getting infinite redirect loop with force_ssl in my Rails app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9448168/why-am-i-getting-infinite-redirect-loop-with-force-ssl-in-my-rails-app)

Spoiler: add this to your nginx config file:

```
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `config.force_ssl = true` and end up in an infinite loop, try this:

In your nginx config change:

```
listen 443 default ssl;
```

to:

```
listen 443;
ssl on;
```

*Credits to pjammer: [Nginx configuration leads to endless redirect loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616521/nginx-configuration-leads-to-endless-redirect-loop)*

Comment: This did not work for me, see my answer below which links to another Stack Overflow question that did solve the problem.