# Why am I getting infinite redirect loop with force_ssl in my Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, redirect, ssl, nginx

I want to have my API controller use SSL, so I added another listen directive to my nginx.conf

```
upstream unicorn {
  server unix:/tmp/unicorn.foo.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
  listen 80 default deferred;
  listen 443 ssl default;
  ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/foo.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/foo.key;

  server_name foo;
  root /var/apps/foo/current/public;

  try_files $uri/system/maintenance.html $uri/index.html $uri @unicorn;

  location @unicorn {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass http://unicorn;
  }

  error_page 502 503 /maintenance.html;
  error_page 500 504 /500.html;
  keepalive_timeout 5;
}
```

which passes the nginx conftest without any problems. I also added a `force_ssl` directive to my ApiController

```
class ApiController < ApplicationController
  force_ssl if Rails.env.production?

  def auth
    user = User.authenticate(params[:username], params[:password])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json do
        if user
          user.generate_api_key! unless user.api_key.present?
          render json: { key: user.api_key }
        else
          render json: { error: 401 }, status: 401
        end
      end
    end
  end

  def check
    user = User.find_by_api_key(params[:api_key])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json do
        if user
          render json: { status: 'ok' }
        else
          render json: { status: 'failure' }, status: 401
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

which worked just fine when I wasn't using SSL, but now when I try to `curl --LI http://foo/api/auth.json`, I get properly redirected to `https`, but then I keep on getting redirected to `http://foo/api/auth` ending in an infinite redirect loop.

My routes simply have

```
get "api/auth"
get "api/check"
```

I'm using Rails 3.2.1 on Ruby 1.9.2 with nginx 0.7.65

Answer (score 130, accepted):

You're not forwarding any information about whether this request was an HTTPS-terminated request or not. Normally, in a server, the "ssl on;" directive will set these headers, but you're using a combined block.

Rack (and force_ssl) determines SSL by:

- If the request came in on port 443 (this is likely not being passed back to Unicorn from nginx)
- If ENV['HTTPS'] == "on"
- If the X-Forwarded-Proto header == "HTTPS"

See [the force_ssl source](https://github.com/seanbehan/force_ssl/blob/master/lib/force_ssl.rb) for the full story.

Since you're using a combined block, you want to use the third form. Try:

```
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
```

in your server or location block [per the nginx documentation](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpProxyModule#proxy_set_header).

This will set the header to "http" when you come in on a port 80 request, and set it to "https" when you come in on a 443 request.

Comment: Pure magic. :)

In my case I was moving a Rails site over to using Varnish. The site was pure HTTPS, and as Varnish doesn't support SSL and Passenger exposes a socket rather than a port, two Nginx server configs were required, one either side of Varnish. Distancing the Passenger socket connection from the HTTPS config on port 443 caused a redirect loop. And this fixed it. Thank you!

Comment: Spent hours looking for this answer.  Thank you!

Answer (score 23):

Try setting this directive in your nginx `location @unicorn` block:

`proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto https;`

I had this same issue and investigating the Rack middleware handler (not `force_ssl` but similar) I could see that it was expecting that header to be set to determine if the request was already processed as being SSL by nginx.

Comment: This will mark all requests as SSL requests, even port 80 requests, since it's a combined server block.