# trying to force a redirect to https from application controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why am I getting infinite redirect loop with force_ssl in my Rails app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9448168/why-am-i-getting-infinite-redirect-loop-with-force-ssl-in-my-rails-app)

I have this in my application controller:

```
before_filter :redirect_to_ssl!

def redirect_to_ssl!
  redirect_to "https://" + request.host + request.fullpath if !request.ssl? && Rails.env.production?
end
```

However, when I view my site (in production mode) with https:// it goes in a redirect loop...  It appears that request.ssl? returns false even though I am using the https protocol.....  Now, when I view my site, the browser does warn me that my ssl certificate can't be verified-- I am wondering if that is why request.ssl? returns false?  What is a good workaround?  Should I just check to see if the request.protocol == "https://"  ?

Answer (score 4):

Don't do this in the controller.

Instead, in `config/environments/production.rb` (and whichever other environments you want to use SSL), do this:

```
config.force_ssl = true
```

Read more info on [configuring Rails 3 to use HTTPS](http://www.simonecarletti.com/blog/2011/05/configuring-rails-3-https-ssl/).

Comment: unfortunately this also results in a redirect loop...

Comment: Did you remove the redirect from your `ApplicationController`? If you have any other redirects, mind posting the code?

Comment: yes I removed it from app controller...  No other redirects..  The problem must lie in the fact that the SSL cert can't be verified..

Comment: This did not work for me.