# nginx redirect loop with ssl

Tags: redirect, ssl, nginx, redirect-loop

This is a very similar problem to [Nginx configuration leads to endless redirect loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616521/nginx-configuration-leads-to-endless-redirect-loop) but that discussion has not led me to an answer yet. I'm learning how to work with nginx and ssl and everything works perfectly on the regular http:// example.com side of things, but when routing to the https:// example.com/admin I instead see:

> This webpage has a redirect loop

Here is my config file:

```
map $uri $example_org_preferred_proto {
        default "http";
        ~^/(images|css|javascript)/ "none";
        ~^/admin/ "https";
}

server {
    listen 80;
    root /usr/share/nginx/www/example.com/blog;

    server_name example.com;
        if ($example_org_preferred_proto = "https")
            return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
        }

    location ~ / {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:2368;
    }

}

server {
    listen 443;
    ssl on;
    root /usr/share/nginx/www/example.com/blog;

    server_name example.com;
    ssl_certificate /usr/share/nginx/<redacted>.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /usr/share/nginx/<redacted>.key;
    if ($example_org_preferred_proto = "http") {
        return 301 http://example.com$request_uri;
    }

    location ~ / {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:2368;
    }


}
```

Basically what I want to accomplish is having a site that normally runs unencrypted, but when I point to my admin page the browser redirects to https and encrypts my login.

Note: the mapping idea came from http://www.redant.com.au/ruby-on-rails-devops/manage-ssl-redirection-in-nginx-using-maps-and-save-the-universe/ and seems like a much better approach than using rewrite

Answer (score 30, accepted):

When nginx encounters a `https` protocol it thinks it is still using `http` as the protocol and is not being forwarded with the rest of the headers, try adding:

```
proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
```

in your location blocks to fix it.

Comment: If you are using `cloudflare` please see @Zaki Aziz answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/56387228/1410291

Answer (score 23):

I've toyed around with other answers but nothing worked for me. Then I realized since I use Cloudflare the problem may not be in the server but with Cloudflare. Lo and behold when I set my SSL to `Full (Strict)` everything works as it should!

[image]

Comment: I've been trying to sort this for HOURS. Thanks for this, solved my issue!

Comment: Thank you, I had same problem here and after updating the cloudflare setting it works fine.

Comment: This was also the case for me, ubuntu 20.04.3 fresh installation with nginx. Setting the encryption mode from flexible to full in Cloudflare solved the 301 redirect loop.