# Nginx https reverse proxy infinite loop

Tags: redirect, nginx, flask, gunicorn, supervisord

this is my site-available nginx configuration for flask application

```
server {
    listen                     80;
    server_name                _;
    access_log                 /var/log/nginx/nginx_access.log;
    error_log                  /var/log/nginx/nginx_error.log;
    rewrite ^ https://$http_host$request_uri? permanent;
}

server {
    listen                     443;
    server_name                _;
    access_log                 /var/log/nginx/nginx_access.log;
    error_log                  /var/log/nginx/nginx_error.log;

    ssl                        on;
    ssl_certificate            /etc/nginx/ssl/<redacted>.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key        /etc/nginx/ssl/<redacted>.key;
    ssl_session_timeout        5m;
    ssl_protocols              TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers                "HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5 or HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5:!3DES";
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;

    location / {
        proxy_pass             http://127.0.0.1:5000;
        proxy_redirect         off;
        proxy_set_header       Host $host;
        proxy_set_header       X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header       X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header       X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        }
}
```

I have gone through the questions
[Nginx configuration leads to endless redirect loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616521/nginx-configuration-leads-to-endless-redirect-loop)
 and [nginx redirect loop with ssl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23121800/nginx-redirect-loop-with-ssl). I seem to have the configuration specified in them already.

**EDIT**

Flask application is running via gunicorn/supervisord

Supervisor config.conf

```
[program:config]
command=/usr/local/bin/gunicorn run:app --config /etc/gunicorn/gunicorn.conf --preload
directory=/srv/<application>
autostart=true
autorestart=true
startretries=10
stderr_logfile = /var/log/supervisord/<application>-stderr.log
stdout_logfile = /var/log/supervisord/<application>-stdout.log
user=root
```

Gunicorn gunicorn.conf

```
bind = '0.0.0.0:5000'
backlog = 2048
workers = 3
worker_class = 'sync'
worker_connections = 1000
timeout = 30
keepalive = 2
accesslog='/var/log/gunicorn/gunicorn_access.log'
errorlog='/var/log/gunicorn/gunicorn_error.log'
pidfile = '/tmp/gunicorn.pid'
loglevel = 'debug'
```

Flask Application

run.py

```
from app import app
from app import views

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=True)
```

view.py

```
from app import app, session
from flask import render_template, json, jsonify
import datetime



@app.route("/hello/")
def render_templates():
    return render_template("display.html")

(... other code ..)
```

NB: I have an ELB in front of the flask application. 80 and 443 ports are open.

Input: https://example.com/hello/ Output: Redirected Loop

Any help will be appreciated.Thanks in advance.

Comment: No. the backend doesn't redirect. @JoeDoherty

Comment: Post your flask code for the endpoint.

Comment: I'm not seeing a redirect loop BTW, I'm get connection refused. Is the loop only present behind the ELB?

Comment: sorry for the wrong address. I have changed it to example.com.

Site is internal to the company. Hence can't publish it here.

Comment: Ok no problem. We are going to need to see the Flask config and some code though. Can't see any dramas in the above.

Comment: @JoeDoherty edited with flask/gunicorn/supervisor content.
Please let me know, if anything else is needed.

Comment: Can I confirm that the ELBs are only passing TCP traffic and not do anything with the SSL connection?

Comment: @JoeDoherty  You may. But not sure how to check that.

Comment: Not sure I don't use AWS :'( ensure that if port 443 is open it is not decrypting the SSL itself and simply passing the encrypted traffic straight through. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/elb-listener-config.html

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92064/discussion-between-munai-das-udasin-and-joe-doherty). @JoeDoherty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did figure out the issue.

The nginx configuration should have been

```
server {
    listen                     80;
    server_name                _;
    access_log                 /var/log/nginx/nginx_access.log;
    error_log                  /var/log/nginx/nginx_error.log;

    location / {
        proxy_pass             http://127.0.0.1:5000;
        proxy_set_header       Host $host;
        proxy_set_header       X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header       X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
```

As ELB does an unloading of HTTPS encryption to HTTP request , my previous configuration was redirecting all my HTTP requests into HTTPS.