# Access Control Request Headers, is added to header in AJAX request with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post, http-headers

I would like to add a custom header to an AJAX POST request from jQuery.

I have tried this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: url,
    headers: {
        "My-First-Header":"first value",
        "My-Second-Header":"second value"
    }
    //OR
    //beforeSend: function(xhr) { 
    //  xhr.setRequestHeader("My-First-Header", "first value"); 
    //  xhr.setRequestHeader("My-Second-Header", "second value"); 
    //}
}).done(function(data) { 
    alert(data);
});
```

When I send this request and I watch with FireBug, I see this header:

> OPTIONS xxxx/yyyy HTTP/1.1
>       Host: 127.0.0.1:6666
>       User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:11.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/11.0
>       Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
>       Accept-Language: fr,fr-fr;q=0.8,en-us;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
>       Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
>       Connection: keep-alive
>       Origin: null
>       Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
>       **Access-Control-Request-Headers: my-first-header,my-second-header**
>       Pragma: no-cache
>       Cache-Control: no-cache

Why do my custom headers go to `Access-Control-Request-Headers`:

> Access-Control-Request-Headers: my-first-header,my-second-header

I was expecting a header values like this:

> My-First-Header: first value
>      My-Second-Header: second value

Is it possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I add a custom HTTP header to ajax request with js or jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7686827/how-can-i-add-a-custom-http-header-to-ajax-request-with-js-or-jquery)

Comment: The title of the question should state that **"For Other Domain"**

Comment: This is an `OPTIONS` request (so-called pre-flight request) to understand if remote host is willing to receive requests at all. You should look at the actual (i.e. `POST`) request to see if it has all the headers properly set.

Answer (score 140, accepted):

What you saw in Firefox was not the actual request; note that the HTTP method is OPTIONS, not POST.  It was actually the 'pre-flight' request that the browser makes to determine whether a cross-domain AJAX request should be allowed:

http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/

The Access-Control-Request-Headers header in the pre-flight request includes the list of headers in the actual request.  The server is then expected to report back whether these headers are supported in this context or not, before the browser submits the actual request.

Answer (score 485):

Here is an example how to set a request header in a jQuery Ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  beforeSend: function(request) {
    request.setRequestHeader("Authority", authorizationToken);
  },
  url: "entities",
  data: "json=" + escape(JSON.stringify(createRequestObject)),
  processData: false,
  success: function(msg) {
    $("#results").append("The result =" + StringifyPretty(msg));
  }
});
```

Comment: thx, i know send Ajax Request with custom Header. My problem is with different domain.. All my custom headers are put into Access-Control-Request-Headers. it's just security in browser : cross-domain.

Comment: yeah, in browser cross-domain requests can cause some difficulties. you can always use some proxy script to send your cross-domain requests

Comment: How do I add the headers with API KEY?

Comment: @Si8 please check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5517281/place-api-key-in-headers-or-url

Answer (score 208):

This code below works for me. I always use only single quotes, and it works fine. I suggest you should use only single quotes *or* only double quotes, but not mixed up.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'YourRestEndPoint',
    headers: {
        'Authorization':'Basic xxxxxxxxxxxxx',
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN':'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
        'Content-Type':'application/json'
    },
    method: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: YourData,
    success: function(data){
      console.log('succes: '+data);
    }
  });
```

Comment: thx, i know send Ajax Request with custom Header. My problem is with different domain.. All my custom headers are put into Access-Control-Request-Headers. it's just security in browser : cross-domain.

Comment: Thanks, I had set headers: "Authorization: Basic XXXXXX" accidentally, and iOS 9 / Safari 9 was throwing SyntaxError DOM 12 on a project.

Comment: Do you mean double or single quotes? I don't think anyone would use double brackets.

Comment: Double or single quotes (not "brackets") have nothing to do here.

Comment: its X-CSRF-TOKEN for the Laravel 5.6 and above

Answer (score 19):

Because you send custom headers so your CORS request is ***[not a simple request](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing#How_CORS_works)***, so the browser first sends a preflight OPTIONS request to check that the server allows your request.

[image]

If you turn on CORS on the server then your code will work. You can also use JavaScript fetch instead ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7686827/how-can-i-add-a-custom-http-header-to-ajax-request-with-js-or-jquery/55584830#55584830))

```js
let url='https://server.test-cors.org/server?enable=true&status=200&methods=POST&headers=My-First-Header,My-Second-Header';


$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: url,
    headers: {
        "My-First-Header":"first value",
        "My-Second-Header":"second value"
    }
}).done(function(data) {
    alert(data[0].request.httpMethod + ' was send - open chrome console> network to see it');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Here is an example configuration which turns on **CORS on nginx** (nginx.conf file):

```html
location ~ ^/index\.php(/|$) {
   ...
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' "$http_origin" always;
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true' always;
    if ($request_method = OPTIONS) {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' "$http_origin"; # DO NOT remove THIS LINES (doubled with outside 'if' above)
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000; # cache preflight value for 20 days
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'My-First-Header,My-Second-Header,Authorization,Content-Type,Accept,Origin';
        add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
        add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain charset=UTF-8';
        return 204;
    }
}
```

Here is an example configuration which turns on **CORS on Apache** (.htaccess file)

```html
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# | Cross-domain Ajax requests                                                 |
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# Enable cross-origin Ajax requests.
# http://code.google.com/p/html5security/wiki/CrossOriginRequestSecurity
# http://enable-cors.org/

# <IfModule mod_headers.c>
#    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
# </IfModule>

#Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "http://example.com:3000"
#Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials "true"

Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "My-First-Header,My-Second-Header,Authorization, content-type, csrf-token"
```

Answer (score 3):

And that is why you can't create a bot with JavaScript, because your options are limited to what the browser allows you to do. You can't just order a browser that follows the  [CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) policy, which most browsers follow, to send random requests to other origins and allow you to get the response that simply!

Additionally, if you tried to edit some request headers manually, like `origin-header` from the developers tools that come with the browsers, the browser will refuse your edit and may send a preflight `OPTIONS` request.

Answer (score 2):

Try to add `'Content-Type':'application/json'`:

```
 $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: url,
        headers: {
            'Content-Type':'application/json'
        }
        //OR
        //beforeSend: function(xhr) {
        //  xhr.setRequestHeader("My-First-Header", "first value");
        //  xhr.setRequestHeader("My-Second-Header", "second value");
        //}
    }).done(function(data) {
        alert(data);
    });
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked for me, but this is an answer to the actual question.

Answer (score 1):

From the client side, I can’t solve this problem.

From the [Node.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node.js) and [Express.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Express.js) side, you can use the *cors* module to handle it.

```
var express    = require('express');
var app        = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var cors       = require('cors');

var port = 3000;
var ip = '127.0.0.1';

app.use('*/myapi',
        cors(), // With this row OPTIONS has handled
        bodyParser.text({type: 'text/*'}),
        function(req, res, next) {
            console.log('\n.----------------' + req.method + '------------------------');
            console.log('| prot:' + req.protocol);
            console.log('| host:' + req.get('host'));
            console.log('| URL:' + req.originalUrl);
            console.log('| body:', req.body);
            //console.log('| req:', req);
            console.log('.----------------' + req.method + '------------------------');
            next();
        });

app.listen(port, ip, function() {
    console.log('Listening to port:  ' + port);
});

console.log(('dir:' + __dirname));
console.log('The server is up and running at http://' + ip + ':' + port + '/');
```

Without cors(), these OPTIONS have to appear before POST.

```
.----------------OPTIONS------------------------
| prot:http
| host:localhost:3000
| url:/myapi
| body: {}
.----------------OPTIONS------------------------

.----------------POST------------------------
| prot:http
| host:localhost:3000
| url:/myapi
| body: <SOAP-ENV:Envelope .. P-ENV:Envelope>
.----------------POST------------------------
```

The Ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: "text/xml; charset=utf-8",

    //These does not work
    //beforeSend: function(request) {
    //  request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'text/xml; charset=utf-8');
    //  request.setRequestHeader('Accept', 'application/vnd.realtime247.sct-giro-v1+cms');
    //  request.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    //  request.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET');
    //  request.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type');
    //},
    //headers: {
    //  'Content-Type': 'text/xml; charset=utf-8',
    //  'Accept': 'application/vnd.realtime247.sct-giro-v1+cms',
    //  'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
    //  'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'POST, GET',
    //  'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type'
    //},
    url: 'http://localhost:3000/myapi',
    data: '<SOAP-ENV:Envelope .. P-ENV:Envelope>',
    success: function(data) {
      console.log(data.documentElement.innerHTML);
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, err) {
      console.log(jqXHR, '\n', textStatus, '\n', err)
    }
  });
```

Answer (score -14):

Try to use the [rack-cors](https://github.com/cyu/rack-cors) gem. And add the header field in your Ajax call.