# Spring MVC filter get custom jquery ajax header

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring-mvc, spring-security

Here's the deal, any help would be greatly appreciated because as of now I am at a loss.

I'm setting custom headers in my jQuery.ajax like so:

```
$.ajax({
type:'GET',
url: url,
dataType: 'json',
headers: {
'customHeader': 'value',
}, etc...
```

I'm using spring mvc and spring security with a custom filter and getting the header like this:

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException,
        ServletException {
    HttpServletResponse httpResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;
    HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
    httpResponse.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    String header = httpRequest.getHeader('customHeader');
```

Unfortunately the header is always null, I've tried things like using beforeSend in the ajax call still same effect. Can anyone please she some light on this?

`Remote Address:127.0.0.1:8080
Request URL:http://localhost:8080/ecom/ws/session
Request Method:OPTIONS
Status Code:401 Unauthorized
Request Headersview parsed
OPTIONS /ecom/ws/session HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
Connection: keep-alive
Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
Origin: null
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.114 Safari/537.36
Access-Control-Request-Headers: accept, ecom_string_s3c, ecom_client_uuid, content-type
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,es;q=0.6
Response Headersview parsed
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Date: Wed, 02 Jul 2014 18:15:03 GMT
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: ecom_string_s3c, ecom_client_uuid, content-type
Content-Length: 0
Server: Jetty(6.1.26)`

Comment: Why dont you use `data` instead of headers in your ajax call....don't reinvent the wheel :)

Comment: I'm basically rolling my own rest authentication implementation and I need the information for authentication to be stored in the header and to be separate from say the post data.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10093053/add-header-in-ajax-request-with-jquery

Comment: I've looked at that several times the answer is quite vague

Comment: basically I need to know how to access the header in my java filter from the httpServletRequest

Comment: If you try `String header = "test";` it returns it??...just for testing purposes...

Comment: http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/servlet/get-all-request-headers-in-servlet/

Comment: yes, it does `String header = httpRequest.getHeader('customHeader');` returns null

Comment: Ok, in your ajax call, if you open the network tab(Chrome, F12 key), can you please post the contents of the ajax call and the headers passed...

Comment: here are the contents of the ajax call

Comment: I added them to original question

Comment: This are your headers...`Access-Control-Request-Headers: accept, ecom_string_s3c, ecom_client_uuid, content-type`...try accesing one of them in your MVC method.

Comment: what would be the syntax for this getHeader('Access-Control-Request-Headers') I would think would just return the keys accept, ecom_string_s3c, ecom_client_uuid, content-type. I need the underlying values for these keys

Comment: I post an answer, please check it

Comment: I'm using the same pattern as you and it works all right for me. I assume these are typos when pasting your code to SO, but just to be sure: You're doing `httpRequest.getHeader("customHeader")` on the server, right? (double quotes). And more crucially: In your ajax call get rid of the superfluous comma after "value": `headers: {
'customHeader': 'value'
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those who come across the same problem, this is an option to resolve this issue.

The problem is with the pre-flight request (OPTIONS). In your custom security filter you don't want to check this, simply because custom headers will **NOT** be sent with OPTIONS requests. OPTION requests are only there to check which methods, origins, headers, etc are allowed.

In your custom filter for token authorization, you could filter out those requests. A quick solution could look like this:

```
 if (methode.equals("OPTIONS")) {
        log.info("OPTIONS REQUEST NO FILTER");
        chain.doFilter(req, res);
    } else {
      //Your filter
   }
```

This way it skips your filter on OPTION requests, and your real request will be sent with the headers allowed by your CORS Filter.

Good luck.

Comment: That is correct, I forgot to answer this question after I found the solution. What you suggested is exactly what I did

Comment: What is `methode` here & How to get methods of request header to check this condition?