# How to get request header from ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am using ajax. Here. i can get response header.

```
var getUrl = $.ajax({
                type: urlType,
                url: url,
                data:data,  
                beforeSend:function(xhr){console.log(xhr)},
                success: function(data) {
                   $('.response').show();
                   $('#resData').val(data);
                   $('#resHeader').val(getUrl.getAllResponseHeaders());
                  // console.log(getUrl.header)
                },
                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                },
                complete: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus) {
                    console.log(XMLHttpRequest)
                }
            });
```

In this, I didn't set headers. by Default, It pass the request header which is shown in network tab.

I have to get request header in beforeSend, success & complete.

How can i get req header from ajax

This req header i can get in network tab

```
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,lzma,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
Host:localhost
If-Modified-Since:Fri, 14 Nov 2014 03:54:43 GMT
If-None-Match:"f60-507c996d5d401"
```

Comment: Which is it? Request headers or response headers?

Comment: I want to get request header

Answer (score -1):

as user milkovsky suggested in another post :

> `$.ajax({
>               type:"POST",
>               beforeSend: function (request)
>               {
>                   request.setRequestHeader("Authority", authorizationToken);
>               },
>               url: "entities",
>               data: "json=" + escape(JSON.stringify(createRequestObject)),
>               processData: false,
>               success: function(msg) {
>                   $("#results").append("The result =" + StringifyPretty(msg));
>               }
>       });`

that's an example of custom headers.

Comment: for more help refer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10093053/add-header-in-ajax-request-with-jquery