# How to set ajax header for post rquest using $.post()

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am using `$.post()` for post method ajax calls and i have to include a header using `beforeSend()` method but how to make it work in `$.post()`.

I know i can work it with `$.ajax()`

Comment: See if it's help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10093053/add-header-in-ajax-request-with-jquery

Comment: it is explained with `$.ajax()`. is there a way to use it with `$.post()`

Comment: `$.post` is shorthand for `$.ajax({type: "POST"})`. You can use `$.ajax` for that

Comment: you can setup only `dataType` in $.post() method otherwise $.ajax will be work

Comment: I'm not sure but I think you can't, but why you can't use $.ajax is the same thing for $.post...

Comment: i wanted to know if there was a way to do it directly inside `$.post()`