# Adding HTTP Header to AJAX get request

Tags: javascript, ajax, rest, http-headers

I am trying to make an AJAX call to an API which requires an HTTP header (REST parameters).Currently no data is being returned. I think what is giving the most difficulty is understanding `setRequestHeader`, not even sure if its necessary. In this example , [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536752%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) it takes 2 string arguments: `oReq.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml")` but then where does the authorization header go? Please Help

Currently I have this:

```
var baseURL = "https://api.azuga.com/azuga-ws/v1/live/location.json";

var header = "Authorization: Basic 0JRGDJW587832"; //Made up number

$.ajax({
      url: baseURL,
      dataType: 'json',
      beforeSend: function(xhr){xhr.setRequestHeader(header);},
      success: function(data){
            console.log(data);

 }
});
```

Comment: why you didn't use the `headers` property of ajax request since you use jQuery?

Comment: also note that your `header` is a string, so `setRequestHeader` is not taking two parameters!

Answer (score 1):

Did you tried:

```
var baseURL = "https://api.azuga.com/azuga-ws/v1/live/location.json";



$.ajax({
      url: baseURL,
      dataType: 'json',
      headers: { 'Authorization': 'Basic 0JRGDJW587832' },
      beforeSend: function(xhr){xhr.setRequestHeader(header);},
      success: function(data){
            console.log(data);

 }
});
```

?

also note that your `header` is a string, so `setRequestHeader` is not taking two parameters!

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. headers: { 'Authorization': 'Basic 0JRGDJW587832' } will not work because headers is undefined.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10093053/add-header-in-ajax-request-with-jquery

Comment: @user1837676,then, try giving two parameters to `setRequestHeader`.

Comment: Tried that as well. Now I am at least receiving a 401 error thats saying im unauthorized. However I've tested the header in googles advances rest client extension and it returns a response.

Comment: VM1042:8 Uncaught ReferenceError: header is not defined