# CORS remain on SecurityError: The operation is insecure

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js, cors

I have an http server developped using Express in nodejs.
The server is running locally on port 3000.

There is an html page served (index.html) which call ajax GET contents (as html content-type).
Those ajax content are also served with the same server on the same port, in the same http protocole.

In the node server application, I have added Cors Same Origin headers, but, the index.html is still having error in console: "Security Error: The operation is insecure".

In the browser console, I successfully see the headers from the node Express app about "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", etc ...

Additionally, the same application is also serving another page, and the index.html can successfully get data w/o any Security Error.

Do you have any other advice?

```
function getData(url, type, CType, id) {
  //var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  //xhr.open(type, url, true);
  //xhr.withCredentials = true;
  //xhr.onload = function () {
  //console.log(xhr.responseText);
  //if(CType == 'text/html') { $(id).append(xhr.responseText); }
  //};
  //xhr.send();

$.ajax({
  url: url,
  type: type,
  crossDomain:true,
  cors:true,
  success: function(data){ 
    $(id).append(data);
  },
  error: function(data) {
    console.log('ERROR '+url);
    console.log(data);
  $(id).append(getError(url));
  }
});


getData(location.protocol+'//'+location.hostname+(location.port ? ':'+location.port: '')+'/modules/mymodule', 'text/html', 'GET', '#content');
```

Comment: It looks like both the requests are either HTTP or HTTPS (not a mix). Is that the case? Are there any redirects involved? (Actually, it looks like you are making a request to the *same* origin, why are you just using a relative URL?)

Comment: What browser are you testing in? If you try a different browser do you get a different (and perhaps more enlightening) error message?

Comment: > why are you just using a relative URL?
Hum.. that's a good question.. and there is no reason...
Just tested in relative: getData('/modules/mymodule', 'text/html', 'GET', '#content');
and I'm having the same result.

Comment: initially tested with Firefox 44.0.2
and Chromium 48.0.2564.82 gives: "SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'open' on 'XMLHttpRequest': 'TEXT/HTML' is not a valid HTTP method."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> initially tested with Firefox 44.0.2 and Chromium 48.0.2564.82 gives: "SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'open' on 'XMLHttpRequest': 'TEXT/HTML' is not a valid HTTP method."

You have your middle two arguments backwards.

> ```
> getData(location.protocol+'//'+location.hostname+(location.port ? ':'+location.port: '')+'/modules/mymodule', 'text/html', 'GET', '#content');
> ```

The second argument should be `"GET"` and the third argument `"text/html"`.

Comment: ohhhh.... dear ... I'm feeling so ..... stupid ...

Answer (score -1):

Try adding these three parameters in the ajax call from your client to the server

```
  crossDomain:true,
  cors:true,
  contentType:"application/json;charset=utf-8",
```

Edited one:

```
 $.ajax({
   url: url,
   type: type,
   method:"GET",
   crossDomain:true,
   cors:true,
   contentType:"application/html;charset=utf-8"
   success: function(data){ 
     $(id).append(data);
   },
  error: function(data) {
    console.log('ERROR '+url);
    console.log(data);
   $(id).append(getError(url));
  }
});
```

Also if you didnt get this approach right try this:

[Add Header in AJAX Request with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10093053/add-header-in-ajax-request-with-jquery)

Comment: unfortunately it ends with the same error.

Comment: `crossDomain:true,` causes jQuery to suppress the custom HTTP headers it normally adds to an XHR request to the same origin in case it gets an HTTP redirect to a different origin. If this was the problem, the error would be complaining about the Access-Control-Allow-Headers header.

Comment: `cors:true,` is not a option supported by the ajax function. It will be ignored.

Comment: `contentType:"application/json;charset=utf-8",` makes no sense at all. The OP is making a GET request, there is no request body to describe the content-type of.

Comment: yes it does not make sense as your return datatype is html

Comment: crossDomain, cors, contentType (as html, json) : not solving.
Add headers in "$.ajax(" : what header did you suggest?

Comment: @KartikeyaSharma — No, it doesn't make sense because there is no content to describe the type of. It is entirely possible (albeit unusual) to make a JSON encoded POST request and get some HTML in the response, but that isn't what is happening here, it is a GET request, there is no request body to describe the content type of).