# Microsoft ASP.NET WebHooks "Expecting exactly one 'ms-signature' header field in the WebHook request but found 0."

Tags: webhooks

Using Microsoft ASP.NET WebHooks, I am getting the error message: "Expecting exactly one 'ms-signature' header field in the WebHook request but found 0. Please ensure exactly one 'ms-signature' header field"

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://localhost:50003/api/webhooks/incoming/custom",
        data: JSON.stringify({
            WebHookUri: "http://localhost:50003/api/webhooks/incoming/custom",
            Secret: "12345678901234567890123456789012",
            Description: "My first WebHook!"
        }),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        "ms-signature": "3499c60eea227453c779de50fc84d315b9a55a20",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data, status) { alert(status); },
        failure: function (errMsg) { alert(errMsg); }
    })
    .done(function (data) {
        alert(data);
    })
.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus) {

    console.log(jqXHR);
    alert('Something went wrong: ' + textStatus);
})
```

Comment: Care to explain what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: My Web hook code not geting access through post ajax request and showing Expecting ms-signature

Comment: Addded context: Microsoft ASP.NET WebHooks

Answer (score 0):

So, as the error message explained, it is expecting a header called 'ms-signature', as opposed to a body content. You can [add headers to the ajax request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10093053/add-header-in-ajax-request-with-jquery) using the header field like so:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://localhost:50003/api/webhooks/incoming/custom",
    headers: { "ms-signature": "3499c60eea227453c779de50fc84d315b9a55a20" }
    ...
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: how do we configure this "ms-signature" ??