# Custom headers for ajax and php

Tags: php, ajax

So, I'm having a problem retrieving custom headers from ajax call.

This is my ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'api.php',
    type: 'get',
    processData: false,
    beforeSend: function(xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader('HASH', '5c268592cd4db9c7f6b813bb689005c6');
    },
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
        console.log(xhr);
    }
});
```

And in my api.php, I have this:

```
<?php
    $headers = getallheaders();
    print_r(json_encode($headers));
```

the output:

```
......
"Access-Control-Request-Headers":"content-type,hash",
....
```

This returns null:

```
echo $headers['hash'];
// or this echo $headers['HASH'];
```

Comment: Do a `var_dump($_SERVER)) and check if you see the header there (might be called `X-HASH` since it's a custom header).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add Header in AJAX Request with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10093053/add-header-in-ajax-request-with-jquery)

Comment: dont found "result" in console.log?.

Comment: What xhr ? Where did you define it?

Comment: @ÖzgürCanKaragöz - `beforeSend: function(xhr) { ... }`. That part is correct: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: `var_dump($_SERVER)` returns
`"HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS":"content-type,hash"`.  No `X-HASH` or something like that

Answer (score 0):

You are making a [cross-origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) request (you *shouldn't* be, since your code shows a relative URL, but perhaps there is an HTTP redirect in play somewhere) and adding custom headers.

This means that it is not a simple request, but requires a [preflight OPTIONS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#Preflighted_requests) request.

The output you see is the headers of the OPTIONS request asking permission from the server to send the request with the custom headers.

You need to grant that permission, then the browser will make a second request (which is the one you are expecting).

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://example.com/");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: HASH, Content-Type");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET");
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this $_SERVER["HTTP_HASH"];