# Jquery - ajax beforeSend basic authentication not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to send a request using ajax to a server which is protected by basic authentication with the following code:

```
$('document').ready(function(){
        $.ajax({
          url: "https://somesite.com/somefolder",
          type: "POST",
          dataType: 'jsonp',
          beforeSend: function(xhr) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader ("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa('myusername' + ":" + 'mypassword'));
            },
          success: function(data){
            console.log('SUCCESS!');
          },
          error: function () {
            console.log("error");
            }
        });         
});
```

So I provide the credentials in the **beforeSend** so my expectation would be that there would be no credential popup from the browser since I already provided the credentials but unfortunately when i run this code I get the popup to enter my credentials. I want to the code to provide these credentials.

Comment: I've deleted my answer, thanks for the clarification.

Comment: It sounds like the site hosting your JS is giving you a 401, right? Not the site that you're trying to hit with ajax.

Comment: @wholevinski When the page loads I get no error in the console. The JQuery CDN I use works fine. The only thing that shows first in the authentication popup. If I enter the credentials it works fine, if I press cancel instead then I get a 401 (unauthorized) error as expected. I tried running a similar request in POSTMAN with the basic credentials added to the header and it works fine so the server is working fine

Comment: You can't send headers or do POST using `jsonp`. It is a script request not really ajax. Suspect you want `json` and need to check if api is CORS enabled. Postman is not subject to CORS restrictions

Comment: A plaintext password and username in a place where the user can view it is not much of a password right?

Answer (score 0):

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10093053/add-header-in-ajax-request-with-jquery), example using headers:

```
    $.ajax({
      url: "https://somesite.com/somefolder",
      type: "POST",
      dataType: 'jsonp',
      headers: {"Authorization": "Basic " + btoa('myusername' + ":" + 'mypassword')},
      success: function(data){
        console.log('SUCCESS!');
      },
      error: function () {
        console.log("error");
        }
    });
```