# Protected API Routes in Laravel

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, api

I have protected laravel api routes now I want to access each route using ajax after the user is Logged In. The Login is api is working and access token is also generated, now I dont know how to use that access token to access different APIs in on different pages of the application.

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth:api']], function () {

 Route::get('/user', function (Request $request) {
     return $request->user();
 });

});
```

I want to access user route using jquery ajax

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/api/user",
            data:({
                _token: "{{ csrf_token() }}",

            }),
            success: function(result)
            {
              console.log('Success');
            }
         });
       });
```

Comment: I would assume you need to add the token in to the `Authorization` header of the request: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10093053/add-header-in-ajax-request-with-jquery

Comment: For API authentication which package used? is it `passport`?

Comment: I know that but how can I get token at different pages of the app ..........

Comment: I am using laravel passport

Comment: `how can I get token at different pages of the app` login and then store the token in a cookie/localstorage/sessionstorage

Comment: I was thinking about doing that but I thought there may be different way of handling this in laravel

Comment: There won't be. Laravel is server side.