# What to do after running curl command in the command prompt

Tags: javascript, json, api, curl, cmd

After I run this in the 
`curl -H "Authorization: MySecretAPI" \ "https://api.pexels.com/v1/search?query=people"`
How do I use this in my JSON project in this format

`$.getJSON(URL, function (data) {...` What should I put for URL, what is the endpoint

Comment: What does a curl command have to do with ajax?

Comment: `https://api.pexels.com/v1/search?query=people` is your endpoint

Comment: "error": "Authorization field missing"

Comment: So you have to set the header on the ajax request. Ref: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/  search for the headers property.  You may can also give them on the `getJSON` method, otherwise you will have to revert to the `ajax` method.

Comment: how do I add a header

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Access Control Request Headers, is added to header in AJAX request with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10093053/access-control-request-headers-is-added-to-header-in-ajax-request-with-jquery)

Comment: I just want an endpoint to use. I can look it up and I get a response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the authentication header.

try that

```
$.ajax({
  url : 'https://api.pexels.com/v1/search?query=people',
  dataType: 'json',
  headers: {'Authorization': 'MySecretAPI'},
  success : function(data) {
     console.log(data);
  }
});
```