# Access to fetch has been blocked by CORS policy - Fetch() JS issue

Tags: javascript, fetch

I have to update the profile's property in klaviyo with API.  so I made this JS. but for some reasons, it doesn't work with me! This is API guide to update profile's property. I followed it but showing this issue!  Could someone help me to fix this issue? many thanks

[image]

https://apidocs.klaviyo.com/reference/profiles#update-profile

```
  const options = {method: 'PUT', headers: {'Accept': 'application/json', 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'}};

  fetch('https://a.klaviyo.com/api/v1/person/01FHGADW5PW4SF33JMWPSN9KQX?api_key=pk_d3af8ba75d110725231231ba795f05ffe77fb&$locale=es-US', options)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(response => console.log(response))
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Also, this ajax's result is the same. still showing the same issue. I'd like to get profile info! The first is to update the profile, second is to get profile info. but all is not working! very sad!

```
  var $email = '1919@gmail.com';
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: `https://a.klaviyo.com/api/v2/people/search?api_key=pk_d3af8ba75d110725231123ba795f05ffe77fb&email=${$email}`,
    success: function(res){
      console.log(res);
    }
  });
```

Comment: You have acces to server?

Comment: Yes @MaikLowrey

Comment: do not post the api_key publicly like this. Instead , put a placeholder for understanding. Delete the key and generate another one immediately

Comment: @jaysurya  thanks! it's just for placeholder

Comment: Maybe this could help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55584963/13604954

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The access control header has to be put on the server, not on the client. If you don't control the server, there's nothing you can do about this.

Comment: Is there any solution to update data on the client slide?

Comment: Did you see this? https://apidocs.klaviyo.com/reference/javascript-client-library

Answer (score 1):

Putting you private key in a browser is a terrible idea.  It allows ANY visitor to your website to then be able to access all of your admin API.

Klaviyo explicitly does not support CORS on the API requests for exactly this reason.  See Klaviyo's response to a similar question here.  https://community.klaviyo.com/apis-40/does-klaviyo-api-support-cors-requests-704?postid=2253#post2253

The correct way to do this is to have a server that you control make the requests to Klaviyo's api.  You can make requests to your server from the JS.