# How to use rate limit in azure api management by using custom apiKey other than subscripon id?

Tags: api, azure, azure-api-management

It is easy to rate limit the api by using,

```
<rate-limit-by-key calls="3" renewal-period="15" counter-key="@(context.Subscription.Id)" />
```

But i need to rate limit the api by using a apiKey send as a request parameter.

Answer (score 0):

First, I assume from your example that you want to specify an element of the request itself as the `counter-key` instead of the subscription ID (as shown in your example). If that's correct, then...

[The docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-access-restriction-policies#LimitCallRateByKey) give the following example of using a [policy expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-policy-expressions) to specify the `counter-key`.

```html
<policies>
    <inbound>
        <base />
        <rate-limit-by-key  calls="10"
              renewal-period="60"
              increment-condition="@(context.Response.StatusCode == 200)"
              counter-key="@(context.Request.IpAddress)"
              remaining-calls-variable-name="remainingCallsPerIP"/>
    </inbound>
    <outbound>
        <base />
    </outbound>
</policies>
```

Assuming the API Key you mention is something that would be passed in as a request header, looks like you would be able to do the following:

```html
<rate-limit-by-key counter-key='@(context.Request.Headers.TryGetValue("YourApiKey"))' ... />
```

Looks like you can use a multi-line policy expression if you want to handle the case of the ApiKey not being included in the request at all:

```html
<rate-limit-by-key 
  counter-key='@{
    if (context.Request.Headers.TryGetValue("YourApiKey", out value))
    {
      if(value != null && value.Length > 0)
      {
        return value;
      }
    }
    return null;
  }' 
  calls='@{
    if (context.Request.Headers.TryGetValue("YourApiKey", out value))
    {
      if(value != null && value.Length > 0)
      {
        return 500;
      }
    }
    return 0;
  }' 
  ... 
/>
```

NOTE: I haven't tested any of the suggested policies here, but I *think* the last one here would allow 500 requests per period per `{YourApiKey}`, and if the Api Key isn't supplied, no requests would be allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are passing the api-key as a header (which is a best practice, source: [Place API key in Headers or URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5517281/place-api-key-in-headers-or-url))  the rate-limit should look like this:

```
<rate-limit-by-key calls="3" renewal-period="15" counter-key="@(context.Request.Headers.GetValueOrDefault("x-api-key", "default-value"))" />
```