# How to add the Api Key as Authorization header with its key value

Tags: react-native, header, authorization, api-key

As in postman their is type authorization called `Api Key` it gives three parmaters, `Key`, `Value` and `Add to`.

I have set `Key to SECRET_KEY` and `VALUE to sdsfdsfsdf3343` and `Add to: Headers`

This successfully working at my backend, And I am able get that value their.

How would I set this Api key to header from my app, How to add authorization header with Key value in javascript react-native application

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like this?

```
fetch('https://mywebsite.com/endpoint/', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    Accept: 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    Key: 'sdsfdsfsdf3343' <------------ Put your key here?
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    firstParam: 'yourValue',
    secondParam: 'yourOtherValue',
  }),
});
```

Comment: it menas I don't need to add authorization with it

Comment: I depends on what you want at the backend side, normally I send something like:
`Authorization: Bear yourJwtToken` in the header

Comment: at this say it should be in authorization headers https://stackoverflow.com/a/5518085/5097662

Answer (score 0):

```
headers: {
    Accept: 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    SECRET_KEY: 'sdsfdsfsdf3343'
  }
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! While this answer may provide a solution for the OP's needings, please, add an explanation in order to make it more understandable, not only for the OP, but also for the whole community