# Any benefit passing api key in header vs url if over https?

Tags: api, security, api-key

I've seen some conflicting information about this. Is there any benefit these days with most web apps being served over https, putting an api key in the header vs as a parameter in a URL???

I had someone freak out about it and my understanding is that it makes no difference over https.

Comment: You are correct given just the request itself. However, it's probably easier to keep out of logs if it's in a header. URLs are often logged in lots of places.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Place API key in Headers or URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5517281/place-api-key-in-headers-or-url)

Comment: That question doesn't address the part in the question about HTTPS, although I doubt if the answer will change because of it. Note that TLS is applied *before* HTTP in HTTPS, so both the URL and the headers will be protected.