# Request source server domain via cURL in PHP

Tags: php, curl

I have 2 web servers, Server A & Server B. Both running PHP5 + Apache + Ubuntu environment.

Server A sends a request via cURL in PHP to Server B. I would like to get the source server domain of the request. As far as I know, `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` can get the IP of the source server (Server A). If I want to get the domain of Server A, how can I get it?

p.s. Server A hosts multiple domains, thus reverse IP resolve does not work in this case.

Here are the codes :

```
$data = array('user' => $user, 'pass' => $pass);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://ServerB/handler.php');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PORT, 80);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 0); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data); 

$ans_xml = curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: You could add it as a http header maybe? Or as one of the data fields? I don't think regular HTTP requests add the domain to the headers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?  
$data = array('user' => $user, 'pass' => $pass, 'appid' => 'pukeko');
$domain = $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"]; // user the super global $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"] or set it  manually to, ex: http://www.myserver.com 

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://ServerB/handler.php');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PORT, 80);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 0); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $domain); // USE CURLOPT_REFERER to set the referer 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data); 

$ans_xml = curl_exec($ch);
?> 

<?
// ServerB - http://ServerB/handler.php
$referer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];  // http://www.myserver.com 
?>
```

The super global **$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"]** will only work if you call **scriptA** via apache, ex: "**wget http://serverA/scritptA.php**"

**UPDATE:**

You can also send  `$domain = $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"]` in your post data:

```
$domain = $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"]
$data = array('user' => $user, 'pass' => $pass, 'appid' => 'pukeko', 'icomefrom' => $domain);
```

and in http://ServerB/handler.php get it with:

```
$icomefrom = $_POST['icomefrom'];
```

This way you don't have to worry with fake referers.

Comment: that's perfect ! but how to prevent someone is forging the same request ?

Comment: Can you password protect the folder where he script is located ?

Comment: Sure it can, but you didn't mention any problem with that in your question, also, I've asked you if you could password protect the folder where the script is located but you didn't answer, so, I'm not sure how I can help you more.

Comment: I've updated the answer so you don't have to worry with fake referers,  check it out.

Comment: read the updated answer, but people can also make the same requests using the parameters.

Answer (score 1):

As stats Pelshoff in his comment above, you should use custom HTTP header:

[Custom HTTP headers : naming conventions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561381/custom-http-headers-naming-conventions)