# designing a restful api: naming URIs, custom headers?

Tags: api, rest

EDIT:  I've solved my issues (for now at least).

I've recently been working with the [Zendesk REST Api](http://www.zendesk.com/api/rest-introduction) and their use of the custom "X-On-Behalf-Of" header for looking up tickets opened by a particular user got me thinking about Restful Api design choices (in no specific language, more of a how to name URIs question).  I've also read [this related question on Custom HTTP headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561381/custom-http-headers-naming-conventions), but it left me with more questions than answers.

Say I have an example restful web service dealing with rental apartment applications where clients use Basic Auth (keep it simple) to authenticate.  Define the basic data as such:

- Users (can be of type landlord or renter)
- Forms (which consist of one or more Document resources and some form meta data like form name and version info)
- And then some type of resource corresponding to Rental Applications, which ties together Forms, Applicants (one or more renters), Landlord, and some metadata like status and dates.

I'm struggling to properly model the URIs for the Applications resource in general, and more specifically with respect to a clients role.  (assume api root is https://api.example.com/)

How do I allow a Landlord to fetch a list of applications sent to them?  My intuition says make a request to "GET /applications" and Basic Auth lets the server know which user to build the list for; likewise "GET /applications" requested by a Renter would return a list of applications they've sent...but I'm not confident this is a solid design in general to mix and match sender vs. recipient lists at the same URI.  Should I be thinking about the "/applications" resource differently, and perhaps allowing a hierarchy like "/applications/[USER_IDENTIFIER]" for each user instead?

Also, regardless of my applications URI design, assume a Landlord is able to create an application on behalf of a renter.  Is this better accomplished by sending a custom header like "X-Create-On-Behalf-Of:  somerenter@example.com" with the PUT/POST creation request?  Or should my schema define a  field which allows for this alternative scenario.

I'm very much an amateur at this, so I'm open to any criticism of my assumptions/design, as well as any pointers for learning more about designing RESTful api's.  Thanks for reading.

Comment: Before you consider using an x- header, please read this http://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-saintandre-xdash-03

Comment: +1 for @DarrelMiller , didn't even think about the X-header issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I've found a solution.

Landlords and Renters are really just subclasses of the same object, which I'll call Party (as in party to a transaction, not birthday party). So then each one has their own resource, named like /party/PARTY_ID.

It's easy to extend this to see that /party/SOME_LANDLORD/applications and /party/SOME_RENTER/applications solve my issues.  It also removes my need to consider custom headers.