# Standards to follow for custom Request Headers

Tags: http, xmlhttprequest, httprequest

I'm adding a custom request header to my jQuery AJAX call and was wondering if there are standards / best practices to follow on specifying the name of your custom header. I see a lot of non-standard headers start with X-. Should I do something like this? Does it matter?

```
"X-My-Header" : "value"
```

Comment: Duplicate question.  You are on the correct track. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561381/custom-http-headers-naming-conventions

Answer (score 1):

If you're minting new HTTP headers I recommend you read Mark Nottingham's [Web API Versioning Smackdown](http://www.mnot.net/blog/2011/10/25/web_api_versioning_smackdown).