# Versioning in ASP.NET Wep API

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

How do I handle versioning in my ASP.NET Web-Api project? I need to have certain functionality version specific:

example:

```
/v1/people
/v2/people/friends
```

How do I implement this in Web-API? Do I use different controllers or actions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Versioning REST API of an ASP.NET MVC application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9197931/versioning-rest-api-of-an-asp-net-mvc-application)

Comment: Hi Darin, I've seen that post, but not totally sure how to implement it properly?

Comment: Which of the many possible solutions described in the duplicate post are you having troubles with implementing? What have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply said: You need to create a custom IHttpControllerSelector and register it via HttpConfiguration.Services. An IHttpControllerSelector has the responsibility for selecting a controller based on the request.

There is actually a library you can use for it:
https://github.com/Sebazzz/SDammann.WebApi.Versioning 
http://damsteen.nl/blog/implementing-versioning-in-asp.net-web-api