# React Native open link in browser with request body

Tags: react-native

Currently I'm using `Linking.openUrl(yourUrl?params)` to open links into a browser, but it is very limited if you need to send parameters with that URL. Right now, the only way to do it is add them as params in the URL. The issue I'm running into is I'm trying to link from an app into a website and I want to auto login the user when landing on the site. The way to do this is to send session tokens that are way too long for the URL as parameters so that the website can use those tokens to determine who is landing on the page and auto log them in.

Is there a way to link from an app to the browser and send parameters in the body or a POST or something?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React Native Linking to Web with http POST?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39324459/react-native-linking-to-web-with-http-post)

Comment: The way I would do this is the OATH route.  Send an AJAX call  POST with the long session token, retrieve a temporary "access token" that is valid to your system for, say 60 seconds -- Then use that access token in the GET parameter to log your user in, and disable that temporary acces token on login.