# Open Url with POST method in Safari using sharedApplication openURL method

Tags: ios, swift, url, mobile-safari, open-uri

I have made URL Request including some parameter in body and http method is set to POST which load in webView successfully.
Now i want to do same process in default browser i.e safari 
but safari accept only URL not URL Request.
I want to know how to typecast/convert this request(NSMutableURLRequest) so that i can accommodate it in the [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL ....

i checked below link but nothing is giving clear idea...

[Open Url hosted using POST method in Safari using sharedApplication openURL method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13196192/open-url-hosted-using-post-method-in-safari-using-sharedapplication-openurl-meth)

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is that you can't do that. The `UIApplication` `openURL` command takes a URL, not a URLRequest. Period.

Furthermore, Safari is not set up to accept URL requests.

As someone pointed out in the other thread, you **can** pass an `URLRequest` to a web view.

Comment: I would also like to point OP to this question which achieves what he's trying to do: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13196192/open-url-hosted-using-post-method-in-safari-using-sharedapplication-openurl-meth?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @AndreaGottardo The OP referenced that link in his question.

Comment: My bad, didn't realize that.