# Share information between iOS app and native Safari app

Tags: ios, safari

I would like to start a communication between my app and Safari.
In my app i'm storing data in the **Keychain** and i know that i could use `UICKeyChainStore` to share these data between apps, but i would like to know if i could also share with Safari native app, making Safari read some data stored in the **Keychain** (or else access my app database) and/or pass data to my app.

I've been looking without success. What i really want is to know if it's "**possibile**" or not, before spending time reading documentations and so on. Everything for now should be handled on mobile devices (**iPhone & iPad**).

A possibile solutions that i found working is to create another (2°) app implementing a `webView`, and i can transfer data to auto-compile fields from my other (1°) app, but accessing directly the Safari native app would be better for my purpose.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: The new [shared web credentials](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Security/Reference/SharedWebCredentialsRef/) API may be what you're after, but you can't create keychain items so that Safari can (or would!) access them. If you're wanting to pre-fill form fields, I'd look at using HTTP GET variables (even if you send the data from the app to a backend that returns a unique token, which you send to the site in the URL so the site can fetch the data from the backend).

Comment: @moonie Are you able to find a solution? For me I want to sent auth token from my app to Safari so that it gets automatically logged in

Comment: @anoop4real no, I couldn't find any solution unfortunately.

Comment: @moonie In this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9880922/ios-is-it-possible-to-open-nsurlrequest-directly-in-safari/ they are saying something about NSURL query components...not sure it works...

Comment: @anoop4real It's another problem anyway, what i wanted to do was to share data between the app and Safari, so that while you were browsing in safari you could access that informations, say anytime you wanted, without opening the app. There instead they wanted to continue browsing in safari with the app as the entry point of the use case. I think anyway there is no solution for this, iOS does not support this feature.

Comment: @moonie my problem is this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32995648/send-authentication-token-to-safari-from-ios-app-to-safari do you know any solution?