# Does there exist any specifications for HTTP 202 status monitors?

Tags: rest, http, asynchronous

The [HTTP 202 Accepted](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.2.3) response is used to accept a task for background processing, and optionally providing a separate URL for monitoring the progress of the task. All [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14832983/http-status-202-how-to-provide-information-about-async-request-completion) and [posts](https://restfulapi.net/http-status-202-accepted/) I've read about it basically suggest everyone to invent their own response types for the submission and monitoring endpoints.

Does there exist any specifications / proposals / conventions (followed by multiple companies) as to how the monitoring URL is returned (an HTTP header or response payload) or what the structure of the monitoring API response is?

Failing that, does any big names (Google, Twitter, etc) implement this pattern in their public APIs, from which to gain insight?

Comment: Care to elaborate why this is off-topic / opinionated? I specifically read the instructions on "best practice" questions and phrased exact questions. The first one can be answered by a link to a spec or "No" (as already done). The second can be answered by a link to API docs or "None of the biggest five Internet companies use such APIs".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does there exist any specifications for HTTP 202 status monitors?

As far as I can tell, as of October 2018 the answer is no.

If there were a standard, I would expect it to appear as a media type (analogous to [RFC 7807: Problem Details](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7807) ) or as some interesting entries in the [Link Relations registry](https://www.iana.org/assignments/link-relations/link-relations.xhtml).