# Pass Authenticity token through http header

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, restful-authentication

I have a rails application that uses a token to authenticate the user. Currently I am passing the token as params. I would like to change this. I believe it is possible to pass it through html header. I dont understand how to use `authenticate_or_request_with_http_token do |token, options|`.
My rails app is actually a server for my iphone client. I things I dont understand are:

1. I know `options` is nonce but how will that work out between my client and server?
2. How do I actually use this in my server code.
3. I can use `authenticate_or_request_with_http_token do |token, options|` to check for token in the the header but how do I insert it into the header once a session is created successfully.

Here is my server Sessions Controller:

```
def create
if @user && @user.authenticate(params[:password])
 # @token = @user.auth_token
 @user.auth_token = SecureRandom.hex 
 @user.save
    respond_to do |format|
        format.json {render :json => {:status => "200", :message => "Logged in successfully", :auth_token => @user.auth_token}}
    end
else
    respond_to do |format|
        format.json {render :json => {:status => "401", :message => "wrong credentials"}}
    end
end
  end

  def destroy
    if(@user)
      @user.auth_token = ""
      @user.save
      respond_to do |format|
         format.json {render :json => {:status => "200", :message => "logged out successfully"}}
      end
    else
      respond_to do |format|
         format.json {render :json => {:status => "401", :message => "No User"}}
      end
   end
  end

def user
  @user = User.find_by_auth_token(params[:auth_token])
end
```

Comment: to set custom headers you use `response.headers`, something like `response.headers["X-AUTH-TOKEN"] = auth_token` should work.. to read the header you use `request.headers["X-AUTH-TOKEN"]`

Comment: this works, Thank you. If you post it as an answer I will accept it :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

to set custom headers you use `response.headers`.

Something like

```
response.headers["X-AUTH-TOKEN"] = auth_token
```

should work.. to read the header you use

```
request.headers["X-AUTH-TOKEN"]
```

the `X-` in the naming is a good practice convention, all custom headers should have an `X-` in front.

Comment: The use of X- is deprecated.

Comment: @m.samy i think that you are right, source (http://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-appsawg-xdash-02) but that looks like a draft.. do you know if that document was accepted?

Comment: More discussion on X- prefix vs no prefix: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561381/custom-http-headers-naming-conventions

Comment: Do you know how can I set this header in Android?