# How do I avoid 401 (Unauthorized) when creating a new API endpoint for Solidus / Spree?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree, rabl

I'm doing a `PUT "/api/shipments/H10372375236/ready_for_pickup"`, but that stops in `Spree::BaseController#authenticate_user`.
My PUT request does not contain any X-Spree-Token header as required by [BaseController#api_key](https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/master/api/app/controllers/spree/api/base_controller.rb#L117-L119)

This is the code for my button:

```
 <%= form_tag(spree.api_ready_for_pickup_path(shipment), { method: "PUT", remote: true, id: "admin-ship-shipment" }) do %>
   <%= submit_tag Spree.t(:ready_for_pickup), class: "ship-shipment-button" %>
 <% end %>
```

This is my routes:

```
Spree::Core::Engine.routes.draw do
  namespace :api, defaults: { format: 'json' } do
    put '/shipments/:id/ready_for_pickup' => 'shipments#ready_for_pickup', as: :ready_for_pickup
  end
end

Rails.application.routes.draw do    
  mount Spree::Core::Engine, :at => '/' 
end
```

`rake routes` available as a Gist [here](https://gist.github.com/081bb4f652e0c07d90e0757e1fcbdb7a).
I have created an API key for the current user in the admin interface.
How do I make sure the PUT request contain the missing X-Spree-Token?

Answer (score 0):

I would be in favor of [that SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17081499/pass-authenticity-token-through-http-header), which is to set the header in the update action of your controller like so:

```
response.headers["X-Spree-Token"] = auth_token
```

Comment: `auth_token` is not present in `Spree::Api::ShipmentsController`

Comment: Here, `auth_token` is to be replaced with your "X-Spree-Token" ;)

Comment: Yeah, but as I write in the initial post, I have no X-Spree-Token. :-(

Comment: Your x-spree-token IS your api key! (check out https://guides.spreecommerce.com/api/summary.html at "Making an API Call")

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by sending `spree_api_key` as a token param on the form.

```
    <%= form_tag(spree.api_ready_for_pickup_path(shipment), { method: "PUT", remote: true, id: "admin-ship-shipment" }) do %>
      <%= hidden_field_tag :token, try_spree_current_user.spree_api_key %>
      <%= submit_tag Spree.t(:ready_for_pickup), class: "ship-shipment-button" %>
    <% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's working using token in params as you said, but in the documentation it's recommended passing it in headers like this :

```
Authorization: Bearer API_KEY
```

(of course, replace API_KEY by your own api key)

source : https://solidus.docs.stoplight.io/authentication