# Creating my own custom header for versioning REST API

Tags: rest, http-headers

I am re-designing my previous century app (which works very well, mind you), and the chance to start fresh has me investigating several aspects. This question is re. versioning.

The app is really collection of data apps that deliver resources--query is http and response is JSON. Now I want to change one of the responses. After reading around, I have decided to **not** implement versioning via the URI or `query_string`. Instead, as advised in [Best practices for API versioning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/389169/best-practices-for-api-versioning), especially the second answer (is there not a way on Stackoverflow to link to a specific answer?), I am using headers. However, instead of using `Accept: application/vnd.company.myapp.customer-v3+json` I am using

```
Accept: application/json
X-Requested-With:   XMLHttpRequest
X-Version:  2
```

On the server side I am able to check the value for `X-Version`. If it doesn't exist, the query uses the latest API. It `X-Version` does exist, then the request version is used. The above works fine.

My question is -- any gotchas I should be aware of? Esp. since I pulled this `X-Version` out of my butt. As far as I know, it is not an officially sanctioned header.

**Update:** Drats! even before posting this I read [Custom HTTP headers : naming conventions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561381/custom-http-headers-naming-conventions), and it seems I should not use the `X-` prefix. However, then there is a possibility of my home-grown header conflicting with an existing standard unless I first do due-diligence. Thoughts?

Comment: Why have you decided not to use media type versioning? What "scope" does your X-Version (or MyCompany-Version) pertain to?

Comment: honestly, I didn't use media type versioning because I don't know what it is and why I should use it. I can't answer the second question because I don't understand the meaning of "scope" in the context of the question. Perhaps you mean what does `X-Version` refer to. Specifically, it refers to the resource being requested. In other words, the query is saying, "get me the resource at the end of this URI using the API version 2 which is applicable **only** to this resource." In other words, other resources can continue use their own respective API versions.

Comment: it is so meaningless to close a 10 years old question that already has a number of responses. Contrary to what the esteemed editor thinks, I am not asking for opinions. I am asking for the right way to program something

Answer (score 2):

I prefer the custom header especially with the current trend of reverse proxy with microservices and traffic management among application versions.

```
X-App: <app_name>:<app_version>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a *lot* of debate around the "right" way to do this. For some high level thoughts, check out mnot's: [WEB API VERSIONING SMACKDOWN](http://www.mnot.net/blog/2011/10/25/web_api_versioning_smackdown)

For a very in-depth discussion, check out this post to API-Craft: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/api-craft/E8MBkzirdcw

Personally, I favor a combination of media type versioning, and link relation versioning, to accomplish this.

Comment: Great reads, those links you provided. However, I still need some clarity. Example: I have a URI that returns JSON that is already being used by an iOS app. Now I want to change the structure of the returned JSON, but I don't want the existing app (installed on lord knows how many devices) to break. Using `X-Version` works. The URI doesn't change, but different versions of apps can get the correct data. Also, since versioning is per URI, an app can use URIs of different versions. How does media-type and link-relation versioning fit in such a scenario?

Comment: Are you trying to make a breaking change to the format? Or an addition?

Comment: In this case the change may not break anything, but that is my guess. Only the app developer would know for sure. I do intend to follow [semantic versioning](http://semver.org), but I have to make a sustainable API design principle. I can't possibly guess whether my changes will break other people's apps. What I can do is provide some kind of versioning so they can choose to use whichever version they desire.