# Pass string variable from Perl CGI script to HTML frontend

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cgi

I'm new to **AJAX** and I have some problems with passing variables back to the HTML script.

I am using a **XAMPP** webserver, **JavaScript** and **jQuery** for the HTML script and a **Perl cgi** script as backend.

I need to take an input string, pass it to the CGI script where it will be used in a Perl function. 
The resulting string variable from the Perl cgi script needs to be passed back to the HTML frontend and be used for a function inside the `$(document).ready(function(){})`.

As of now, I am able to pass a user defined input to the cgi script and display the result as a simple HTML text. But how can I use the cgi output as a variable for further JavaScript/jQuery functions?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

This is my HTML and JavaScript code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>AJAX example</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="_lib/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.jstree.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function() {

            /*
            I need to use the string variable "#searchtext" in this example function:

            $("#filter").click(function () {
                $("#testtree").jstree("search",$("#searchtext").val());
            });
            */

        });

    </script>

    <script language="Javascript">

        function xmlhttpPost(strURL) {
            var xmlHttpReq = false;
            var self = this;
            // Mozilla/Safari
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                self.xmlHttpReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
            }
            // IE
            else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
                self.xmlHttpReq = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            self.xmlHttpReq.open('POST', strURL, true);
            self.xmlHttpReq.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
            self.xmlHttpReq.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (self.xmlHttpReq.readyState == 4) {
                    updatepage(self.xmlHttpReq.responseText);
                }
            }
            self.xmlHttpReq.send(getquerystring());
        }

        function getquerystring() {
            var form     = document.forms['f1'];
            var word = form.word.value;
            qstr = 'w=' + escape(word);
            return qstr;
        }

        function updatepage(str){
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = str;
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>      
    <form name="f1">
        <p>word: <input name="word" type="text">  
        <input value="Go" type="button" onclick='JavaScript:xmlhttpPost("/cgi-bin/ajax_test.cgi")'></p>
        <div id="result"></div>
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

This is my Perl script ajax_test.cgi:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use warnings;
use CGI;

my $query = new CGI;

my $word = $query->param('w');

print $query->header;
print "<p>You are searching for: <b>$word</b>.</p>";
```

**Update:**

I tried to use the first solution suggested by *collapsar* but I'm still not sure where to put the js vars because I need to be able to call them *inside* the `$(document).ready(function(){})`:

```
<script language="Javascript">

function xmlhttpPost(strURL) {
    //...//
}

function getquerystring() {
    //..//
}

function updatepage(str){
    //...//
}

var resp_html = self.xmlHttpReq.responseText;
var resp_dom  = jQuery.parseHTML(resp_html );
var mydata1 = $('#<custom-id-1>', resp_dom).text();

// the alert doesn't work
$("#alertbutton").click(function () {

    alert( "You entered: " + mydata1);

});
```

Answer (score 1):

### option 1: content processing

you have to parse the content from the server on the client if you transmit (semi-)structured data, ie. html or xml. to simplify access to the data of interest, issue id attributes to the tags/elements you will be generating server-side.

server-side code (augmenting you sample):

```
print "<p>You are searching for: <b id="<custom-id-1>">$word</b>.</p>";
```

client-side retrieval and processing:

```
var resp_html = self.xmlHttpReq.responseText;
var resp_dom  = jQuery.parseHTML(resp_html );

var mydata1 = $('#<custom-id-1>', resp_dom).text();
```

the code snippet presumes, based on tha tags on your questions, that you use jquery (in case you don't why not?). you can also resort to plain dom methods, see the applicable [documentation on mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser).

if you resort to a plain text response, there will be no need for markup and thus no need to parse the response and extract the relevant data with dom methods. you would get the desired data by text search & replace operations. which way to go depends on the complexity and intended use of your data.

caveat: what you best avoid is using html/xml and extract the information using search & replace. while technically feasible in many settings, it's usually a nightmare in maintainability and quite often breaks down during the evolution (read: integration of new features) of the software.

### option 2: http headers (not recommended)

you have the alternative option to send your information in custom http headers. while this method will circumvent potential problems the parsing the content and the content's encoding, you will most certainly violate the recommendation in [rfc 6648](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc6648.txt) (for a discussion see [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561381/custom-http-headers-naming-conventions)).

having said that, the method is technically viable. in your perl script use

```
print $query->header(
    { 
        '<custom-header-1-name>' => '<custom-header-1-value>'
      , '<custom-header-2-name>' => '<custom-header-2-value>'
# ...          
    }
);
```

for client-side retrieval, use:

```
var mydata1 = self.xmlHttpReq.getResponseHeader('<custom-header-1-name>')
var mydata2 = self.xmlHttpReq.getResponseHeader('<custom-header-2-name>')
// ...
```

the tags to your question suggest that you're using jquery anyway (in case you don't, why not? ;-)), so while you're at it have a look at the [jquery ajax api](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

Comment: Thank you very much for your extensive answer. I'm trying the first option right now: I added a new button (`<button id="alertbutton" class="button">Alert</button>`) to the HTML code and tried to set an alert to see if I can use the variable mydata1:  
`$(document).ready(function() {
 
 $("#alertbutton").click(function () {

  alert( "You entered: " + mydata1);
 });
 
});`
Where do I need to initialize the three variables resp_html, resp_dom and mydata1?
And you're right, I'm using jquery as well and will have a look at the jquery ajax api. I'm still pretty new to both jQuery and JavaScript.

Comment: `document.ready` is not the right place for your alert - you are fetching the data _asynchronously_ (that's what the first a in 'ajax' stands for), so you have no guarantee that the result arrives before the dom of the master html page (the one containing the ajax call) has been built (which is when `document.ready` will be called). easiest will be to place the processing and testing inside the `done` callback of the jquery `ajax` object (see the link in my answer). while experimenting, declare the js vars globally (**not recommended in production code**).

Comment: I tried to declare the js vars globally but the alert is still not working. I updated the code in the question, maybe you could have a look and tell me what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: ok, _declare_ your variables (`var ...`) globally as the very first statement in your javascript (before the functions), _define_ them (assign the values) inside `xmlhttpPost`.

Comment: I did, but the alert button is still not working: Instead of a pop-up window appearing the input field goes blank and the url changes to "http://localhost/ajax_alert.html?word=entryword".

Comment: you must include the server part in your url (`http://your.serv.er/cgi-bin/ajax_test.cgi` instead of `/cgi-bin/ajax_test.cgi`).

Comment: But if the url were wrong, I shouldn't get a response by clicking on the "Go" button and I do get the answer from the cgi script "You are searching for: [...]".