# HTTP header resundant header

Tags: http

Is adding an **extra redudandant** header to the HTTP request may cause any functionality harm?

for example:

Adding :

myheader=blablabla

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561381/custom-http-headers-naming-conventions.

Answer (score 0):

An `X-` prefix [was customary for those headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561381/custom-http-headers-naming-conventions), but no longer. It shouldn't break anything as long as your headers are formatted correctly (so: `myheader: blablabla`, not `myheader=blablabla`)

Comment: Surely myheader: blablabla :-) Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The [HTTP 1.1 specification](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec7.html#sec7.1) says (about entity headers);

> Unrecognized header fields SHOULD be ignored by the recipient and MUST be forwarded by transparent proxies.

In other words - since the wording is SHOULD, not MUST - recipients are allowed to react to unknown headers, so technically your extra header *could* cause harm.

In practice though I have never seen a recipient do this, and with the surfacing of [newer RFCs regarding custom header use](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6648) seeing an adverse effect is very unlikely.