# What is the general custom http header names used in mobile application development?

Tags: http, http-headers, naming-conventions, mobile-application

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561381/custom-http-headers-naming-conventions) helps me a little bit about convention, but I want to ask what are they in practice.

For example:

- Which http header name to send device specific information like deviceId?
- Which http header name to send device type? (e.g.: tablet, mobile, etc.)
- Which http header name to send device os?

I did not see any complete information about these topic.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there are headers that tell you the device or OS. Some of the information you want can be extracted from the `User-Agent` header.

For screen sizes there can be headers too, like `UA-pixels`, but they cannot really be trusted (no header can be, actually).

Comment: I know there is no default support, Instead of, I am asking what people are using (custom headers) to carry these informations and their variations.

Comment: And that is exactly the question I answered. There is no separate header that tells you the OS.