# Angular JS HTTP Response header not working on Safari

Tags: angularjs, safari, http-headers, httpresponse

I am stuck in a problem where I am posting an object, in response I should get some header from the HTTP response. The problem is this code is working fine in browsers like Chrome, Firefox, IE but it returns `null` in case of Safari (Windows).

```
 $http.post(url, data)
         .then(function(response){
                console.log(response.headers("location"));
                // response.headers("location") is null in Safari
         });
```

Below are the response headers I am getting from the server.

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:http://localhost:5000
Access-Control-Expose-Headers:ETag,Location
Content-Length:0
Date:Mon, 15 May 2017 12:46:14 GMT
Location: //my API
Server:Microsoft-IIS/8.5
X-Powered-By:ASP.NET
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your safari is an old version that works according to the old recommendations that every custom header must be prefixed with X-
see this link:
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561381/custom-http-headers-naming-conventions)