# What is the correct format to get Django Header value when Header name contain `_` underscore

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, django-views

My CURL command:-

```
curl -X POST \
  http://localhost:8000/sendData/ \
  -H 'authorization: Token b67d31c42d98b3c97b28c737629dca63ef5043fc' \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -H 'client_cdata: virat' \
  -H 'clientdata: sachin' \
  -H 'content-type: multipart/form-data;' \
  -H 'postman-token: ed70d17c-ecf6-66c7-619e-85eac7d62803' \
  -F purchasID=23124212 \
  -F purchaserAmount=4320'
```

I tried to get Header Data

using `request.META['HTTP_CLIENTDATA']`

I got the value `sachin` same as when i try to get  `request.META['HTTP_CLIENT_CDATA']` it not working,
It's showing the `*** KeyError`  error.

What is the correct format to get Header value when header name contain `_`?

> I can't change header data, Because of this API is called by another
>   domain(It result provided by another site or server), I'm creating API
>   end points.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks like your curl has a missing `'` at `content-type`.

Comment: Thanks, Do you have any idea how can I access `request.META['HTTP_CLIENT_CDATA']` this

Comment: This is 3rd party response data, i checked on `META` `HTTP_CLIENT_CDATA` not presents.

Comment: look on the output of `self.request.META.keys()`

Comment: `HTTP_CLIENT_CDATA` not present on the list Why ?

Comment: `HTTP_CLIENTDATA` present on the list

Comment: i can't find the docs but simple you can not use `_` in the headers just replace it to the `-` and you will can get value by `self.request.META.get('HTTP_CLIENT_CDATA')`

Comment: here the help [http-headers-naming-conventions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561381/custom-http-headers-naming-conventions)

Comment: change the `client_cdata`header to `client-cdata`(change underscore to hyphen). And in django get it with `self.request.META.get('HTTP_CLIENT_CDATA')`

Comment: I can't change that, Because of this API is called by another domain(It result provided by another site or server), I'm creating API end points.

Answer (score 0):

Working on the assumption that you're probably using either Nginx or Apache as a reverse proxy, headers containing underscores are dropped by these servers to avoid problems when mapping such headers to CGI variables.

If you need to support underscores - which it sounds as though you do, because they're coming from a third party - then you have to enable support.

**For Nginx** ([link](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#underscores_in_headers))

```
underscores_in_headers on;
```

**For Apache** ([link](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/env.html#fixheader))

```
SetEnvIfNoCase ^client.cdata$ ^(.*)$ fix_client_cdata=$1
RequestHeader set client-cdata %{fix_client_cdata}e env=fix_client_cdata
```

Comment: @deependra-singh did this help to resolve your problem?

Comment: I'm not using Apache or Nginx anymore.