# What does the X- prefix mean in HTTP? (e.g. X-API-KEY)

Tags: rest, authentication

Consider [this example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_programming_interface_key) from Wikipedia:

E.g.

```
GET /something HTTP/1.1
X-API-Key: abcdef12345
```

What does the `X-` technically stand for?

Comment: X-prefix just shows that this header is a custom one. You may have a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561381/custom-http-headers-naming-conventions

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From [RFC-6648](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6648), "X" is commonly understood to stand for "eXperimental" or "eXtension" :

> Many application protocols use parameters with textual (as opposed to
> numerical) names to identify data (media types, header fields in
> Internet mail messages and HTTP requests, vCard parameters and
> properties, etc.).  Historically, designers and implementers of
> application protocols have often distinguished between standardized
> and unstandardized parameters by prefixing the names of unstandardized
> parameters with the string "X-" or similar constructs (e.g., "x."),
> where the "X" is commonly understood to stand for"eXperimental" or
> "eXtension".

Answer (score 5):

The X is mostly used to indicate that is an unoffical, not officially specifed or application specific header.