# what is the functionality of below code in .pcapfile

Tags: http-headers, pcap, tcpdump

```
`▒▒+Q4▒▒POST/nspversion=1.0&op=notify&sid=966ca56d500083a311eab9c8af564b1a` `HTTP/1.0^M`
User-Agent: mealso/1.0 (I; en-US)^M

Host: google.com:5001^M

X-Tellme-FetchGUID: 870ee784-b9da-11ea-d9ae-00005e0001ca^M

Content-Type: text/xml^M

Content-Length: 1592^M

X-Tellme-DID: 6247b3b10d76de4facf9ff7bb4c4c7ea^M
```

this code is present in .pcap file of tcpdump, what is the functionality of this code exactly?

Comment: when performed vi filename.pcap saw the above code in cap file, I'm curious what would be functionality of the code

Comment: This is an HTTP request taken out of any useful context. It is unclear in what environment it was captured and when, what the response was, what the source and destination for the request where etc.  It looks suspicious for me in that it claims to connect to  google.com:5001 but that's all I can get from this few information.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich for source, destination and environment details are here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62679340/what-is-the-role-of-http-header-in-tcpdump-and-pcap-file

Answer (score 0):

This is going to be in the HTTP layer of some packet in the packet capture.

All of these are [HTTP headers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields), and not code per se. `User-Agent`, `Host`, `Content-Type`, and `Content-Length` are all HTTP request headers, so this is an HTTP request. `X-TellmeFetchGUID` and `X-Tellme-DID` are non-standard headers, and you can tell this because they [start with X-](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561381/custom-http-headers-naming-conventions).

Comment: this is what im trying to do - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62679340/what-is-the-role-of-http-header-in-tcpdump-and-pcap-file.