# python outlook SetProperty() issue with underscore in string namespace

Tags: python, automation, outlook, mapi

For an email that I send automatically via python with the win32com library I need to add something to the email header property. Code is like this:

```
olMailItem = 0x0
obj = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")
newMail = obj.CreateItem(olMailItem)
newMail.Subject = "test mail"
newMail.BodyFormat = 2
newMail.HTMLBody = html_out
newMail.To = email_recipient
newMail.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/string/%7B00020386-0000-0000-C000-000000000046%7D/_test_", 'xyz')
```

Now I'm having issues with the underscores in the schemaName so it won't accept "_test_". Somehow I can escape the first underscore in the python way with a backslash like that `...%7D/\_test_", 'xyz')` which would then work if I remove the second underscore. However for the second underscore I have not found a solution to escape it so that it is accepted.

Basically Outlook should be able to handle this because I read _test_ out of an exiting email header.

Any clue here? I can not find any restrictions for the [string namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/outlook/how-to/navigation/referencing-properties-by-namespace#string-namespace)

Answer (score 0):

Outlook applies its business logic and also introduces some limitations when dealing with OOM. As a workaround you may try to use a low-level API on which Outlook is based on - Extended MAPI or just any third-party wrappers around that API such as Redemption, for instance. You can try using [MFCMAPI](https://github.com/stephenegriffin/mfcmapi) for playing with property names manually.

Also you may try to append the property name with any meaningful symbol.

Internet headers naming convention is described on the [Custom HTTP headers : naming conventions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561381/custom-http-headers-naming-conventions) thread.