# How to do swagger documenting for header response data in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, swagger

This is testing API, I'm returning my pagination model in header of my API, we have `ProducesResponseType` attribute to documenting response body in Swagger. What about headers, if we return some data in header? How to document that in the header?

```
 [ProducesResponseType(typeof(List<string>), StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
 [HttpGet]
 public async Task<IActionResult> test()
 {
     var paginationModel = new PaginationModel()
     {
         CurrentPage = 12,
         TotalCount = 500,
         TotalPages = 10
     };

     HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add("X-Pagination", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(paginationModel));

     return Ok(new List<string>());
 }
```

Comment: _"I'm returning my pagination Model in header of my API"_ - are you sure that's a good idea?

Comment: Yes, The point of this question is sometimes we need to return something in the header, but I don't know how to document it in swagger

Comment: But you do agree that ["_you're doing it wrong_"](https://knowyourmeme.com/memes/youre-doing-it-wrong) by doing it this way? Is it impossible for you to change your response DTO design to include that data in the body?

Comment: so if i don't return my pagination stuff in the header i have to return it in the body with list of data , and it's not clean , and don't look that code i know it's dirty

Comment: Your opinion on what's "clean" or "dirty" is naive and is demonstrably causing problems for you. Please reconsider what you are doing. RESTful web-services are designed around self-describing resources/responses, and moving _absolutely essential_ information to a response-header means it won't be self-describing, nor easily discoverable for external consumers. This is a bad idea.

Comment: Also, using `X-` as a header prefix is officially discouraged as of RFC 6648 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561381/custom-http-headers-naming-conventions