# RESTful service, how to respond if validation failed?

Tags: http, rest

I have service that takes some entity and needs to save/update this entity:

```
http://myhost.com/rest/entity
```

I use POST and submit JSON. Inside service it detects that entity passed is not good. Not valid, order passed in with customer that doesn not exist, etc.

How should I reply? `HttpCode.NotFound`? Or others? How do you reply to such things?

Comment: Well, that is realy up to you to decide, it's your service.

Comment: possible duplicate of [REST HTTP status codes for failed validation or invalid duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3290182/rest-http-status-codes-for-failed-validation-or-invalid-duplicate)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In our project in such situations we do the following:

1. Set response code to HTTP 400 Bad Request
2. Set response body to the following JSON: `{"message":"%extended error message here%"}`

But it's really very subjective.

Also I'd suggest reading [This blog article on RESTfull error handling](http://www.onlamp.com/pub/wlg/4009) - it describes many available options, so you can choose something for your taste.

Comment: This is what we do. We return the same media type asked for if available. In the web world you get back a 400 with text\html. In this example the media type is application\json

Comment: Thank you! I was thinking about passing some info in header in addition to status code but between article you referred and this posts I think I will decide on common response object for my services and only use 400 and 200 codes (Other than 401 for auth)

Comment: if you're going to return validation errors then 400 is sufficient

Comment: The link is archived at https://web.archive.org/web/20180311152736/http://www.onlamp.com/pub/wlg/4009

Answer (score 35):

[422 Unprocessable Entity, defined in WebDAV (RFC 4918)](http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc4918.html#STATUS_422):

> The 422 (Unprocessable Entity) status code means the server understands the content type of the request entity (hence a 415(Unsupported Media Type) status code is inappropriate), and the syntax of the request entity is correct (thus a 400 (Bad Request) status code is inappropriate) but was unable to process the contained instructions. For example, this error condition may occur if an XML request body contains well-formed (i.e., syntactically correct), but semantically erroneous, XML instructions.

Comment: I really like this. It's probably going to be unpopular with the purists but it is way better that using the same status as a malformed request.

Comment: On the project I'm working on I was also very bothered by the inability for the client to distinguish between validation errors and malformed requests from the status code alone (w/o inspecting response body), and independently thought of using 422 to distinguish the former. I came across this while doing some sanity-check searching to make sure there weren't better alternatives, so I'm glad to see other people have used this approach and that this isn't completely out of left field. May I presume neither of you encountered other downstream issues with this approach?

Comment: This is what I do since the common use of 400 is really not technically correct given that the request isn't bad.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should pick a [client error code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#4xx_Client_Error). **400 Bad Request** or **403 Forbidden** can be a good start

Comment: 418 is the obvious choice there.

Comment: 403 is not appropriate for the described scenario.

Comment: Why is 403 not appropriate? http://stackoverflow.com/a/3290369/59639 Seems like there are different schools of though on 400 vs. 403