# Correct HTTP status code if a POSTed object fails validation

Tags: http

What status code should I set if validation of an object fails in a POST. Using Rest.

Answer (score 5):

400 Bad request - http://restpatterns.org/HTTP_Status_Codes

see also: [REST HTTP status codes for failed validation or invalid duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3290182/rest-http-status-codes)

Comment: return 400 and add an additional response body like:
<errors>
<error>
<code>1</code>
<description>name must not be empty</description>
</error>
</errors> or something like that

Answer (score 1):

The most appropriate one would probably be 400, "Bad Request." The 4xx status codes correspond to client errors.

Answer (score 1):

422 comes to mind (see http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc4918.html#STATUS_422)