# Status code for "already exist"

Tags: web-services, http, rest, webserver

Similar to HTTP status code 500-Internal Server Error,200-OK,201 Created etc... Is there any code for "Already Existing" to be giver as response from server, While trying to create a new object (if the object with same values exists) ??

Comment: 'Already exists' by what semantic? Identical ID? Similar content?

Comment: @Tichodroma 'Already Exists' like object having a similar email_id,contact_number etc... which are meant to be 'unique'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [REST HTTP status codes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3290182/rest-http-status-codes).  In this case, you almost certainly want `409 CONFLICT`.

Answer (score 1):

If your client sends an `If-None-Match`-header like described [here](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-14.26):

> The meaning of "If-None-Match: *" is that the method MUST NOT be
> performed if the representation selected by the origin server [...]
> exists, and SHOULD be performed if the representation does not exist

Then if the same resource exists, you can respond with a 412 Precondition Failed:

> if "*" is given and **any current entity exists** for that resource, then the
> server MUST NOT perform the requested method, unless required to do
> so because the resource's modification date fails to match that
> supplied in an If-Modified-Since header field in the request.
> [...] the server MUST respond with
> a status of 412 (Precondition Failed).

Instead of * (which means "if anything exists") you can also use an Etag, which basically is a checksum of the entity that is calculated by the server. You can detect identical entities by identical Etags.