# Php form ajax "success & fail" message

Tags: php, ajax, forms

The form on my website is a simple contact form.
I would like the form to show a "success & failed" message on the same page when the form is sent/failed without reloading the page. I understand that I should use Ajax to do this but I can't get it to work because my knowledge about it is very little.

Here is the code I'm working with.

Html (single page design):

```
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.js"></script>

<form class="form" id="contactus" action="" method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8">




                        <label for="nametag">Namn<FONT COLOR="#FF0060">*</FONT></label>

                        <input name="name" type="text" id="name"  value="" />




                        <label for="emailtag">Email<FONT COLOR="#FF0060">*</FONT></label>

                        <input name="email" type="text" id="email"  value="" />


                        <label for="phonetag">Telefon</label>

                        <input name="phone" type="text" id="phone"  value="" />


                        <label for="messagetag">Meddelande<FONT COLOR="#FF0060">*</FONT></label></br>

                        <textarea name="message" id="message" style="width: 87%; height: 200px;"></textarea>






<label class="placeholder">&nbsp;</label>

                        <button class="submit" name="submit">Skicka</button>



                </form> 



<script>        
    $(function() {
            $('#contactus').submit(function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                event.returnValue = false;
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'php/mail.php',
                    data: $('#contactus').serialize(),
                    success: function(res) {alert(res);
                        if (res == 'successful') {
                            $('#status').html('Sent').slideDown();
                        }
                        else {
                            $('#status').html('Failed').slideDown();
                        } 
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        $('#status').html('Failed').slideDown();
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Php:

```
<?php
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $recipient = "info@mydomain.com";
    $subject = "Webbkontakt";
    $formcontent = "Från: $name <br/> Email: $email <br/> Telefon: $phone <br/> Meddelande: $message";

    $headers = "From: " ."CAMAXON<info@mydomain.com>" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-To: ". "no-reply@mydomain.com" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n";

    if(mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $headers))
    {
        echo "successful";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "error";
    }
?>
```

Comment: ajaax uses http status codes to determine success/failure. If you want to trigger the 'error:' path in your ajax code, you'll have to return a 4xx or 5xx http status code. Right now you're outputting a `200 OK` with no body, or (still) a 200 OK, with body "Ett fell uppstod". neither of those look like a failure to the ajax system.

Comment: in the php script `echo 'successful';` to satisfy `if (data == 'successful')`

Comment: Could you give me a code back? I understand that I'm doing it wrong but I don't know how to fix it and my knowledge about php & ajax is very poor, so I don't really understand :(

Comment: note: you are only sending 1 value - `data: {email: $('form input[type=email]').val()},`, but expecting 4 -`$name = $_POST['name']; $email = $_POST['email']; $phone = $_POST['phone']; $message = $_POST['message'];`

Comment: yes Sean is right, you are sending only email. Send all data for successful execution. And also echo success or failure for getting response.

Answer (score 3):

Your `Ajax` call is not working properly. Try this

```
$(function() {
            $('#contactus').submit(function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                event.returnValue = false;
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'php/mail.php',
                    data: $('#contactus').serialize(),
                    success: function(res) {
                        if (res == 'successful') {
                            $('#status').html('Sent').slideDown();
                        }
                        else {
                            $('#status').html('Failed').slideDown();
                        } 
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        $('#status').html('Failed').slideDown();
                    }
                });
            });
        });
```

Also as you can see i have used `$('#contactus').serialize()` this way you dont need to pass the form elements one by one instead `serialize()` will pass the whole form elements to your php page

Than in your php file `echo` `successful` if everything went well else `echo` `error` if the response is an `error` than show the `error div`

```
<?php
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $recipient = "info@mydomain.com";
    $subject = "Webbkontakt";
    $formcontent = "Från: $name <br/> Email: $email <br/> Telefon: $phone <br/> Meddelande: $message";

    $headers = "From: " ."CAMAXON<info@mydomain.com>" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-To: ". "no-reply@mydomain.com" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";

    if(mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $headers))
    {
        echo "successful";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "error";
    }
?>
```

Comment: I tried this. I changed both codes. The page reloads, the message does not show and the email is not sent :/

Comment: It should work fine as long as you don't have any other errors on your page

Comment: You have placed the code before including the the `jquery` library. Place it below the form and it will work fine

Comment: the form is being sent but it shows the failed message when submiting

Comment: See the updated `php` code also make sure to use correct email address instead of using `info@mydomain.com`

Comment: So I updated and tried that. Still shows the failed message but sends the form.

Comment: Do an alert after the ajax call and see what it returns write `alert(res);` right after this line `success: function(res) {`

Comment: A window popped up and said successful. When closing it the failed text appeared on the page again.

Comment: Ok i can see it alerts the success but there is a line break added to the response as well. make sure there is no other `echo` is there except for `echo "successful";` and `echo "error";`

Comment: I updated the code here on the top. Well this is the only php file for the website and as far as I know there is no other echos.

Answer (score 1):

Change your PHP script like this:

```
<?php
if( isset( $_POST['submit'] )){ //checking if form was submitted
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$formcontent="Meddelande: \n\n $message";
$recipient = "info@mydomain.com";
$subject = "Webbkontakt";
$mailheader = "Från: $name \n Email: $email \n Telefon: $phone \r\n";

$mailsent = mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader);

if($mailsent) echo "Success"; //success if mail was sent
else echo "Ett fel uppstod!";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Below your `mail()` function, simply do `echo "successful";`

Answer (score 1):

## 2020 Edit

In REST API response should be always accompanied by the correct HTTP status code, with 200+ telling client that request ended up correctly processed or was otherwise good, 400+ telling client there was an error in request, and 500+ that there was a problem with the server itself. Do not use statuses inside responses, it is unnecessary duplication of the existing feature:

```php
http_response_code(200);
echo json_encode(['message' => 'Email was sent']);

exit;
```

Then you can handle request and response with jQuery(assuming that you still use jQuery):

```js
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  data: data,
  dataType: 'json'
})
  .then(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    // Your 200+ responses will land here
  })
  .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    // Your 400+ responses will be caught by this handler
  });
;
```

If you need specific status, you can get it from `jqXHR` parameter using `jqXHR.status` field.

## Original answer

You can use `dataType: 'json'` in your `ajax` call.

Then you'll be able to pass status code as response key:

```
// form response array, consider it was success
$response = array( 'success'=> 'ok', 'message' => 'Email was sent');

echo json_encode($response);
```

In js then you can check `data.success === 'ok'` to know what's your status.

Comment: Use HTTP codes, not arbitrary strings for succes/error statuses.

Comment: [Yes there is](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3290182/rest-http-status-codes).

Answer (score 0):

In your php script you could try this

```
if(mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheaders))
{
  echo("Mail Sent Successfully"); // or echo(successful) in your case
}else{
  echo("Mail Not Sent"); // or die("Ett fel uppstod!");

}
```