# check if username and email is unique in database

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

Tried searching the net for 2 days and still could not find a specific answer. I have the below node.js code for user routes and models. How can I check if the username and email has never appear in the MongoDB, and prompt the user a message if there is?

model:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');

// User Schema
var UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  username:{type: String , required:true, index: true, unique:true},
  email:{type: String, required:true, index: true, unique:true},
  password:{type: String, required:true}
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema)
```

route:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var User = require('../models/user');
var bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');

// Get Homepage
router.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.render('index');
});

router.get('/register',function(req,res){
    res.render('register');
});

// submit form
router.post('/submit', function(req, res){

    // retrieve data from posted HTML form
    var username = req.body.username;
    var email = req.body.email;
    var password = req.body.password;
    var password_confirm = req.body.password_confirm;

    // express validator
    req.checkBody('username','Username is required').notEmpty();
    req.checkBody('email','Email is required').notEmpty();
    req.checkBody('email','Invalid email').isEmail();
    req.checkBody('password','Password is required').notEmpty();
    req.checkBody('password','Password must contain at least 6 characters').isLength({min:6});
    req.checkBody('password_confirm','Password mismatch').equals(req.body.password);

    // store the errors
    var errors = req.validationErrors();
    if(errors){res.render('register',{errors:errors});}
    else {
        // hash password
        var salt = bcrypt.genSaltSync(10);
        var hash = bcrypt.hashSync(password, salt);
        password=hash;

        // load data into model
        var newUser = new User ({username:username, email:email, password:password});
        // save the new user
        newUser.save(function(err,newUser){
            if(err){console.error(err);}
            // console.error is same, but in stderr form
            else{
                console.log('new user saved successfully');
                console.log(newUser);
            }
        });
        res.redirect('/');
    }
});

module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 4):

```
app.post('/authenticate', function(req, res) {
  var user = new User({
    username: req.body.username
  });

  user.save(function(err) {
    if (err) {
      if (err.name === 'MongoError' && err.code === 11000) {
        // Duplicate username
        return res.status(500).send({ succes: false, message: 'User already exist!' });
      }

      // Some other error
      return res.status(500).send(err);
    }

    res.json({
      success: true
    });

  });
})
```

You have to catch the error and return it to the **front end** of your application. This code above should demonstrate how to achieve this by using server status [500](http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E500.html). Regarding searching the web, this answer and question are quite similar to this previous question:

> [How to catch the error when inserting a MongoDB document which
>   violates an unique index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30593882/how-to-catch-the-error-when-inserting-a-mongodb-document-which-violates-an-uniqu)

I hope this helped to some extend.

Comment: thanks for the reply. but I can still save new entries with same username successfully into mongodb. when I use console.log(err), it does not produce any errors. I checked the link of another case you provided, at least there was error message for that case. do you know why I do not have anything in err?

Comment: because you might have not defined variables the same way. Here I see you are using this `var errors = req.validationErrors();` try console logging `errors` and see what actually comes up.

Comment: Is there anyway to differentiate the error for username compared to email? Because I am pretty sure the err.name and err.code remain the same between the two. The reason I am curious is because I would like to let the user know which of the two is already in use instead of having to guess if its the email or username

Comment: @Jake

Hello and sorry for the late response. Check the specific **MongoDB error codes** for this. Alternative way of doing it is by creating a **find** query and search for a duplicate.