# HTTP Status 400 Validation Versus Verification

Tags: rest, http, http-status-codes

Although [RFC 7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231) was intended to bring clarity, it evidently has brought ambiguity regarding status code 400.  Note this [SO answer and the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3290198/284758).  One person says 400 now includes logical, application or **verification** errors, another person says that 400 still is intended only for syntactic or **validation** errors.

> 6.5.1.  400 Bad Request
> The 400 (Bad Request) status code indicates that the server cannot or
> will not process the request due to something that is perceived to be
> a client error (**e.g., malformed request syntax, invalid request
> message framing, or deceptive request routing**).

I would like to get a more definitive answer about this. Consider two scenarios where a POST or PUT attempted to provide an e-mail address:

- The e-mail found in the request failed **validation** (e.g. it contained "hello#gmail.com").  **A 400 reply is sent.**
- The e-mail found in the request failed **verification** (e.g. another user is already using that address).  **A ??? reply is sent.**

I want to follow RFC 7231.  My reading of the 6.5.1 tells me that the verification error should receive a 409 (or 422) response.  But others disagree, and claim it should now be a 400.

Does anyone have more information that would resolve this ambiguity?

Comment: There are hundreds of "Which status code to use in <arbitrary situation>" questions. 400 is a blanket statement, if you can find one that fits the scenario better, choose the more specific one - if you want to. Key is to be consistent.

Comment: The answer is use whatever works best for you.

Answer (score 2):

200 is a fine status code to send in this situation. After all, do HTML forms get a 4xx back when you don't put in a valid post code?

Status codes are for **generic** consumption, not application-specific semantics. They're useful when a non-specific recipient -- e.g., a proxy, a cache, a HTTP library -- can do something interesting when it comes in.

So, 400 is to be used when there are errors stemming from client problems (such as bad request **HTTP** syntax). It was made more generic in 7231 because x00 status codes are the most generic of their series, and should be considered fallbacks when a more specific status code isn't defined.

You can use 400 for a validation error too, and it will be theoretically, slightly helpful in that a HTTP library knows not to repeat that request -- but it certainly isn't worth getting too concerned about if it's 200.