# Show all laravel validation errors in one div when using jQuery ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, validation, laravel-6

I'm using this ajax request to send request using jQuery:

```
 $.ajax({type: 'POST',
             url: '/send-review',
             data: {
                 "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}",
                 "_id": {{$item->id}},
             },
             success: function (data) {
                 console.log(data);
             },
             error: function (err) {if (err.status == 422) { 
// when status code is 422, it's a validation issue

        }
    }
   });
```

I can show get Laravel validation error in the bottom of each input, but
how can I show all of the Laravel validation errors format in one box of HTML using jQuery?

Comment: it's better to use `if( err.status == 422 || err.status == 400 )` for validation problems

Comment: Thanks, @YasserCHENIK but why I must use 400 error code for validation until I can use 422?

Comment: `400` is the generic error code that means `bad request`, you can see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31323100/http-status-400-validation-versus-verification#:~:text=You%20can%20use%20400%20for,concerned%20about%20if%20it's%20200.) post for more details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of way you can show messages . You can print error object . like as

```
var htmlErr= []
var err.errors.map((data,index)=>{
   $(".comment").text(data.comment);  
});
```

in html

```
<p class="comment"></p>
```

then you can try with like this. For more error message more class ..

Its just dummy code for accurate code i need to know details  about your data/object.

Comment: Laravel Validation errors are like this : "errors":{"comment":["The comment field is required."]

Answer (score 1):

### laravel 8

I always use this  :

```
$.ajax({type: 'POST',

             ...

             success: function (data) {
                 console.log(data);
             },
             error: function (err) {
               if (err.status == 422) { 
                   toastError(err.responseJSON.message);
                   let details = res.responseJSON.errors ;
                   Object.keys(details).forEach(field => {
                      formatErrorUsingClassesAndPopover(field,details[field]);
                   });
               }
            }
        });
```

And for Formatting the answer implement the `formatErrorUsingClassesAndPopover( element , array_of_problems )`
make it as abstract as possible .
for example (Using Bootstrap and jQuery):

```
 function formatErrorUsingClassesAndPopover(element , array_of_problems ){
       let someHTML = '';
       array_of_problems.forEach(function(e){someHTML+='<li>'+e+'</li>'});
       $('#'+element+'_error_section').html('<ul>'+someHTML+'</ul>');
       $('#'+element).addClass('is-invalid');
 }

 ...

 //don't forget to use this in the ajax success function :
 $('input').removeClass('is-invalid');//or you can let the client side validation do it
```

Note : To copy past this code you need that if your database column is `field` ,you need :

- your error section's `id` to be `field`_error_section .
- your input's `id` to be `field` .

Comment: Use the bootstrap class `invalid-feedback` in your `error_section`'s div