# HTTP 403 or 406 for post requirements violation?

Tags: http, http-status-codes

Simple question:

I have a POST endpoint which expects some text input. The text input must not be longer than x characters. If it is I'll respond with an error message.

But which HTTP status code will be the correct one?

> 0.4.4 403 Forbidden
>
> The server understood the request, **but is refusing to fulfill it.** 
>   Authorization will not help and the request SHOULD NOT be repeated. [..]
>
> 10.4.7 406 Not Acceptable
>
> The resource identified by the request is only capable of generating response entities which have content characteristics not acceptable according to the accept headers sent in the request.
>
> 10.4.18 417 Expectation Failed
>
> The expectation given in **an Expect request-header field [..] could not be met** by this server [..]

[Source: w3.org](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html)

Comment: just return a bad request

Comment: **400 Bad Request** The request could not be understood by the server due to malformed **syntax**. The name makes sense, the description kinda does not apply tho :|

Comment: of course the data is malformed

Comment: So, data and syntax are actually the same?

Comment: anything the server do not understand is malformed.

Comment: Your argumentation is kinda floppy. It explicitly says **syntax**. But this is probably stuff for hours of discussion. I'll accept it as answer ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess that's existed question.
Shortly the proper HTTP Code is **400 + optional description**.

You can checkout more detailed answer here: [REST HTTP status codes for failed validation or invalid duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3290182/rest-http-status-codes-for-failed-validation-or-invalid-duplicate)