# Which HTTP code to choose when parent resources are missing

Tags: rest, http, web-services, response, httpresponse

Let's consider the following method:

`GET https://server.com/resource1/{id1}/resource2/{id2}/resource3/{id3}/target/{targetId}`

So basically we are getting a `target`. If the target with `targetId` does not exist, we respond with 404 and this is fine. But what about previous resources?

What if `resource1`, `resource2`, `resource3` do not exist?

Is it 404 again? Or is it 400 (not entirely applicable due to HTTP spec though). Or maybe even 424 (because dependent resources are missing)?

I understand there would be no 100% correct answer probably. I'm also aware of [REST HTTP status codes for failed validation or invalid duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3290182/rest-http-status-codes-for-failed-validation-or-invalid-duplicate)

Answer (score 1):

If the document (resource) identified by /resource1/{id1}/resource2/{id2}/resource3/{id3}/target/{targetId} doesn't have a current representation, then you should return 404.

It doesn't matter whether the resource doesn't exist because a lookup based on id1 failed, or a lookup based on id2 failed, or a lookup based on id3 failed, or a lookup on targetId failed.

You can think of a URI as cache key: does this spelling match a resource that has a current representation?

The message-body of the response is available if you want to explain this specific problem.  But status codes and headers are metadata in the "transfer of documents over a network" domain; general purpose components don't care about our implementation details.