# How cookie based authentication was done in server side?

Tags: asp.net, web-services, wcf

Can anyone give examples of how cookie authentication was implemented in webservices or wcf or any asp.net application or give some urls where i can find resources.

I know how token based authentication works. The concept of cookie based authentication sounds new to me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does cookie based authentication work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17769011/how-does-cookie-based-authentication-work)

Comment: I found answer to this question in these pages:




http://blogs.msdn.com/b/odatateam/archive/2010/07/21/odata-and-authentication-part-7-forms-authentication.aspx

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/odatateam/archive/2010/08/19/odata-and-authentication-part-8-oauth-wrap.aspx

I expected an answer something similar to this.

Comment: KnightFox, whether can you confirm if this is correct?

Comment: This also,
http://thoughtorientedarchitecture.blogspot.in/2009/10/flowing-aspnet-forms-authentication.html